# Android ImageView with Rounded Corners not working

Tags: android

I have definied the file thumb_rounded.xml and placed it inside the res/drawable folder in my android application. With this file i want to get rounded corners in my ImageViewthat contains the news thumb,

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners android:radius="13.0dip" />
</shape>
```

and i am setting this as background of my ImageView, however, i dont get the rounded corners, the image remains a rectangle. Does anyone have any idea on how to get that? I want to achieve the same effect as this screen:

[image: B&H first screen]

Many thanks

T

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to provide rounded corners like that to an ImageView. You'll want to follow the code from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners

Comment: Try taking a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners

Comment: I tought there would be a way without having to use java, for example... the B&H android application has a rectangle image with rounded corners at the first screen, i would like to achieve that same effect.

Comment: nope, you'll have to program it. that's the only way.

Comment: copy an iphone design to android is really a bad idea

Comment: Check this now we have `ShapeableImageView` to make circular or rounded  imageView  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61086632/7666442

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're lacking a couple of tags. Here's a new sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>    

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#ff000000"/>

    <padding android:left="1dp"
             android:top="1dp"
             android:right="1dp"
             android:bottom="1dp"/> 

    <corners android:radius="30px"/> 
</shape>
```

Seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310209/android-cant-create-simple-rectangle-shape-unsupportedoperationexception)

Also, are you aware of [RoundRectShape](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/RoundRectShape.html)?

Comment: Your code didnt work. It should a rounded rectangle with white background bigger then my image... I will take a look at the RoundRectShape, thanks @Pedro

Comment: I was just posting a sample, I wasn't adapting the values to the ones you wanted, but it should be very simple to do that!

Comment: It does not seem to work.

Comment: it dows not seem to work

Comment: Why an accepted answer? Does not work!

Answer (score 22):

use it,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle mBundle) {
super.onCreate(mBundle);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
Bitmap bitImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    R.drawable.default_profile_image);
image.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerImage(bitImg));
}

public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
    bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

final int color = 0xff424242;
final Paint paint = new Paint();
final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
final float roundPx = 100;

paint.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
paint.setColor(color);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

return output;

}
```

Here , round corder is depend on roundPx.

Comment: how to make tile mode repeat along with rounded corners ?

Comment: What does new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN) come from?

Comment: Check this now we have `ShapeableImageView` to make circular or rounded  imageView  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61086632/7666442

Answer (score 14):

If you place a view on top of the ImageView that functions as a mask, you can achieve exactly that rounded image effect.

take a look at this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffff"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:src="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    />

<View
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_margin="00dp"
    android:background="@drawable/mask" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and a mask.xml drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />    
    <solid android:color="#0000"/>
    <stroke android:color="#ffff" android:width="10dp"/>   
</shape>
```

Two important things:

1. the stroke width of the mask drawable should match the padding of the ImageView
2. the stroke color of the mask drawable should match the background color.
3. the radius of the mask corners must be adjusted to correspond with the stroke width (so you don't see the image behind the mask).

The sample produces the following image:
[image]

HTH

Comment: what if the background is not a solid background ? this method won't work well since it shows the rounded corners area with a solid background.

Comment: that's true, this will only work if you can define a mask that blends in with the background ( doesn't need to be a solid color, though).

Comment: it's a cool trick though. better than other solutions in case you know for sure that it will blend well with its surroundings.

Comment: Sadly does not work, as the corners all still visible.