# Changing Image as Rounded Corner

Tags: android, json, image

I've one listview with some items. In my listview i've using custom adapter for displaying the items with images. My images in items are coming from `JSON` My images are like this -

[image: Needed]

Now, I just need the image with rounded corner. How do i achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539781/android-imageview-with-rounded-corners-not-working

Comment: you can able to do it with Css/Html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
        bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = 12;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
  }
```

code extracted from http://ruibm.com/?p=184

Comment: I've been experimenting the values for the `roundPx` but the ImageView is somehow oblong. What value should I supply to `roundPx` to get the same shape as the OP's Needed Image?

Comment: roundPX should be the radius of the corner. Check [the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawRoundRect). Try bigger values. [Here](http://android-er.blogspot.nl/2011/08/canvasdrawroundrect.html) you can see an example with radius = 100 and 50

Comment: Not working well when trying to set imageview's scaletype, only fitXY is working, centerCrop and other are showing unpredictable results, anyone here got same issues?

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap myCoolBitmap = ... ; // <-- Your bitmap you want rounded    
int w = myCoolBitmap.getWidth(), h = myCoolBitmap.getHeight();
```

We have to make sure our rounded corners have an alpha channel in most cases

```
Bitmap rounder = Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(rounder);
```

We're going to apply this paint eventually using a porter-duff xfer mode.
This will allow us to only overwrite certain pixels. RED is arbitrary. This could be any color that was fully opaque (alpha = 255)

```
Paint xferPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
xferPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
```

We're just reusing xferPaint to paint a normal looking rounded box, the 20.f is the amount we're rounding by.

> canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0,0,w,h), 20.0f, 20.0f, xferPaint);

Now we apply the 'magic sauce' to the paint

```
xferPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
Now apply this bitmap ontop of your image:

canvas.drawBitmap(myCoolBitmap, 0,0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(rounder, 0, 0, xferPaint);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
            .getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = pixels;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3292810/258415), brilliant answer on how to get rounded edges for bitmap images.