# Rounded corners in imageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

This is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:padding="3dp" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" 

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="208dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ash_arrow" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can i show my `ImageView` with rounded corners?

Comment: If your images are png, then you can create a custom shape in drawable folder, set its corners and color and set as ImageView background.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9517434/940096)

Comment: @Demonick, if i use jpg images, is it applicable too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ash_arrow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <!--Background with solid color-->

    <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>

    <!--background with gradient-->
    <!--<gradient-->
    <!--android:centerColor="#fff"-->
    <!--android:centerX="50%"-->
    <!--android:centerY="50%"-->
    <!--android:endColor="#f0f"-->
    <!--android:gradientRadius="100"-->
    <!--android:startColor="#f00"-->
    <!--android:type="radial"/>-->

    <!--Stoke with dashed line-->
    <!--<stroke-->
    <!--android:width="8dp"-->
    <!--android:color="#f00"-->
    <!--android:dashGap="8dp"-->
    <!--android:dashWidth="8dp"/>-->

    <!--Stroke normal-->
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/willow_grove"/>

    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"/>

</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: how to use this xml ??

Comment: How does this show an image with rounded corners? Doesn't it simply replace the image?

Comment: @AmiguelS: use like this  -> android:background="@drawable/ash_arrow" and set image Original image android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"

Comment: @Aerrow Consider editing your answer, because it is currently wrong.

Comment: @AmiguelS: now its ok?

Comment: @Aerrow I believe it still replaces the original image...

Comment: @AmiguelS: try with this snipped,  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/myred"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_backup_black_24dp"/> you will get the  reslut like above. Or you need via java code use Circular Imageview or Some other libraries. Hope the user posted the question need the above result, yours may varies.

Comment: I do not need this answer, I just happened to see it and noticed it was misleading. On your answer you provide ash_arrow.xml, but ash_arrow is the user drawable, so you are replacing it, instead of adding a frame, which is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

What if you try to set a background to your ImageView, defining a Shape in xml that would only contain a "corner" Attribute? Something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners android:radius="20dip" />
</shape>
```