# how to make full circular image view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make an image fit into a circular frame in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050813/how-to-make-an-image-fit-into-a-circular-frame-in-android)

I want a 360 degree circular shape Image View, I found related solutions on stackoverflow, but they were all yielding rounded corners in image view. But i want full circular image view.

For rounded corners image view links are:

- [Rounded corners in imageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684469/rounded-corners-in-imageview)
- [How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners)

Any thoughts.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Get the Bitmap:

```
Bitmap bitmap = getthebitmapyouwanttoshowinacirclefromsomewhere;
Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Use a shader:

```
BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader (bitmap,  TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setShader(shader);
```

Draw the canvas;

```
Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
c.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getHeight()/2, bitmap.getWidth()/2, paint);
```

Set the image:

```
myImageView.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);
```

Comment: Almost got it... but i want the radius to be fixed say 30dp (thats simple), also i wants that the image which is displayed (circular) is from the center of the original pic...

Comment: You'll want to change the parameters of this method then: `c.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getHeight()/2, bitmap.getWidth()/2, paint)`;

Comment: ya i got the image, but its changing its position in the layout, there is lot of padding/ margin coming on left and top...

Comment: Indeed, you will have to play with the parameters in the canvas and drawcircle depending on your needs

Comment: @Waza_be , make it as a paid answer :-) 

additionally adding : Use square image for circle .