# Screenshot of layout with circular image view makes the image cut

Tags: android, android-layout, android-bitmap

I have a relative layout in my app which im trying to take screenshot of. The problem is that it has CircularImageView in it (https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView) and the whole image is transformed and no longer cropped to center.

The code goes like this:

```
View rl = findViewById(R.id.toBeScreenShot);
rl.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(rl.getWidth(),rl.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(screenshot);
rl.draw(c);
rl.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

And this is the result:

[image]

The XML code is too big to share, there is a Relative layout that im taking screenshot of (in code, its 'rl'). Then there is a FrameLayout, then two LinearLayouts, some ImageViews and then there is the CircularImageView:

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:id="@+id/userPicture"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_120sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_130sdp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:civ_border="false" />
```

Any idea what might cause this thing to happen?

Comment: post also your xml code please

Comment: you start with a CircularImageView fully visible and you end up with this image?

Comment: exactly. Normally, that picture is cropped to center, which means that my head is somewhere above the third emoticon (:-O).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I've been able to figure out that the bug must have something to do with the library that I'm using. So I tried to figure out some other way to create circular image, and I found this answer from Waza_Be:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180142/6148510

After some short testing, the screenshot of this circular bitmap works properly. If there will be no answer to my problem, I will mark this workaround as a correct answer.

Comment: surely, as you can see in the link reported by yourself, you should use width/2 and heigth/2

Comment: if /2 is the solution please write an answer, I'll vote up it

Comment: nope, CircularImageView does the division by itself, also if you notice that the 1/4-circle on the picture is not really a full quarter. Its close but putting 4 of them together would not make a flawless circle.