# How can i add Round Corner method for bitmap in my imageview android?

Tags: android, performance, android-imageview, android-bitmap

Gud Morning friends. I have create Imageview in row of listview. i also set my bitmap in my Imageview like,

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    UserHolder holder = null;
    Log.d("main", "pos:" + "" + position);

            if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new UserHolder();
        holder.Name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);

        holder.Number = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.number);

        holder.img=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);


        Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"helve.ttf");

        holder.Name.setTypeface(face);
        //holder.Number.setTypeface(face);

        //bit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);     
       //

        //holder.img.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(bit, 40));

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    User user = data.get(position); 

    holder.Name.setText(user.getName());
    //holder.img.setImageBitmap(user.getbi());
    holder.img.setImageBitmap(roundCornerImage(user.getbi(),50));
    //holder.img.setImageBitmap(roundCornerImage(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(user.getbi(), R.drawable.ic_launcher),60));
    holder.Number.setText(user.getNumber());




    // Give Different Back Ground To List View---------------------------------------------

    if ((position % 2) == 0) {
        row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_dark);
    } else {
        row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_light);
    }




    Log.d("main", "pos:" + "" + position);

    return row;
```

---

Now I want to set Bitmap Method in My This imageview. with my code. The methos which i want to add is bellow.

```
 public Bitmap roundCornerImage(Bitmap src, float round) {
  // Source image size
  int width = src.getWidth();
  int height = src.getHeight();
  // create result bitmap output
  Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
  // set canvas for painting
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
  canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

  // configure paint
  final Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  //paint.setColor);


  // configure rectangle for embedding
  final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
  final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

  // draw Round rectangle to canvas
  canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, round, round, paint);

  // create Xfer mode
  paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
  // draw source image to canvas
  canvas.drawBitmap(src, rect, rect, paint);

  // return final image
  return result;
 }
```

---

How can i add this method in my code. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: do you have source Bitmap?

Comment: ya i have get contact image in bitmap.

Comment: Closed this question as a duplicate as it's exactly a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839366/set-round-corner-method-in-imageview) asked by you for the same issue. Instead of asking a new question, you should edit your existing question and provide enough details which would let you get good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
holder.img.setImageBitmap(roundCornerImage(user.getbi(),ANY CONSTANT VALUE TO MAKE YOUR IMAGEVIEW ROUND LIKE-1,2));
```

Comment: done, but what is constant value.?? i'm new in android @pratik

Comment: try with one, its for how much round you needed, try with 1 and see how it looks

Comment: ya its ok, try it and let me know.

Comment: brother its not work. my project is force close... NULL POINTER EXEPTION

Comment: ITS REAL CODE IS...  imViewAndroid.setImageBitmap(roundCornerImage(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.custom_bg),60));

Comment: ya then now, what is the problem?

Comment: i want to use user.getbi() in that code. how.??

Comment: user.getbi(), means, what it consist? is it a bitmap or a url? and what is your name?

Comment: ya it is bitmap url of phonebook contact image. my name is Hitesh

Comment: you have to convert that url to bitmap first and then need to pass in that method, url will not work, must need bitmap there

Comment: i have converted it. and set in imageview. now i want to use this in corner imageview bitmap. so how can i?

Comment: if you have correct bitmap then public Bitmap roundCornerImage(Bitmap src, float round) this method must be work perfect.

Comment: check my compite code. n give me some perfect answer brother.

Comment: roundCornerImage(user.getbi(),50), what you get after using this method?

Comment: Null Pointer Exeption in this line... int width = getbi.getWidth();
    int height = getbi.getHeight();

Comment: check your bitmap is null I think

Comment: no brother. without this method mt project is work fine. bitmap is not null. only problem to define this method in imageview.

Answer (score 0):

You can usse this method in adaptor--

```
    public Bitmap getRoundedRectBitmap(Bitmap scalebitmap, int pixels) {
        Bitmap targetBitmap = null;
        try {

            int targetWidth = 150;
            int targetHeight = 150;
            targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
            Path path = new Path();
            path.addCircle(
                    ((float) targetWidth) / 2,
                    ((float) targetHeight) / 2,
                    (Math.min(((float) targetWidth), ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
                    Path.Direction.CW);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            // paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setDither(true);
            paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
            canvas.drawOval(new RectF(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), paint);
            // paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            canvas.clipPath(path);
            Bitmap sourceBitmap = scalebitmap;
            canvas.drawBitmap(
                    sourceBitmap,
                    new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap
                            .getHeight()), new RectF(0, 0, targetWidth,
                            targetHeight), paint);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError o) {
            o.printStackTrace();
        }
        return targetBitmap;
    }
```

And you can write method in some constant class and call this method in adaptor like
//photo is the Bitmap image which you want to convert in round

```
Bitmap bitmapImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, 200, 200,true);
    bitmap = imageprocessing.getRoundedRectBitmap(bitmapImage, 100);
```

Comment: what is imageprocessing.?? @user1170640

Comment: I had written getRoundedRxtBitmap() in Imageprocessing.java file and imageprocessing is the object of that.

Comment: than what is bitmap..???