# White Border along with transparency in "LinearLayout"

Tags: java, android, border, transparency, android-drawable

I wanted to add a linear layout, having a transparent background as well as with white borders. The problem is: as far as I have googled, I can achieve only one out of both.

Here's what I did:

1. Saved the following as border.xml in drawable

   ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item> 
          <shape android:shape="rectangle">
          <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" /> 
     </shape>
     </item>   
        <item android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" >  
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
        </shape>
      </item>    
     </layer-list>
   ```
2. my existing page layout

   ```
        <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/quiz"
           android:layout_width="150dp"
           android:layout_height="120dp"
           android:background="#66041414"          <-------- replaced it with android:background="@drawable/border"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" >

            ......
          </LinearLayout>
   ```

I am getting opaque background, when the border was included.

I wanted a final result to be like: 
 
 
[image: Reference image]

totally stuck with it. Just wanted to find a way out to achieve it. Any suggestions would be quite helpful.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14473235/646806) I answered, way of using `xml` will help.

Comment: @Anurag: Please look at the answer update below with the proof.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Your drawable for background of layout:**

You can change radius for corner shape if you want. But stroke will create a border and solid part is the background which we are making transparent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners
      android:radius="2dp"
      android:topRightRadius="0dp"
      android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" />
  <stroke
      android:width="1dp"
      android:color="@android:color/white" />
  <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

**and my test layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_transparent_linear_layout"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**It works, Below is the proof:**

[image]

Comment: Works indeed... I know my words aren't enough for the help, but still thanks a ton buddy.... u made my day :) :)

Comment: How about a bottom border only?

Answer (score 2):

Xml Drawable for background:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners android:radius="30dp" />
<stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#ffffffff"/>
<solid android:color="#66000000"/>
</shape>
```

Adjust radius,  width and dark color transparency ( #ff and #66 parts) as you please.

Comment: i can set only one value for android:background... its either the border or transparency...
According to your code, I am getting borders, but not transparency.

I hope u got me??


anyways thanks for an optimized code for borders.

Comment: @anurag just edit the colors, first 2 digits are  for transparency (#00 to #ff). I've place default fill color as `#66000000` which is semi transparent black, and default border color as `"#ffffffff"` which is full opaque white.

Comment: @anurag. The color value #FFBBCCDD - FF -> transparency level (00 being the most transparent), BB -> red level (FF -> being fully red), CC -> green level, DD -> blue level. If the color value has only 6 hex characters and not 8 as this one, that means that transparency is ignored (the element is opaque). #FFCCBBDD equals #CCBBDD. Next time at least try the answers because @ Singularity kind of did what you asked in the image.

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use two layout `aligned` one top of the other then set the background `transparent` for the `top view` and set the white border as background for the `bottom view`. You can do this thing inside `relative layouts`.

Comment: Try @VendettaDroid solution.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed well suggestion by @Ali Imran, check below way, hope it will help.

*back.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"> 
         <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#dd7b7a"/>
         <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"/> 
         <solid android:color="#dd7b7a"/>
     </shape>
```

*main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
<LinearLayout 
     android:padding="4dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
<LinearLayout  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:background="@drawable/tile_mode" // your transparent image
    />
</LinearLayout>  
</LinearLayout>
```

also go through below links in that, way of using `xml` will works for you.

[Bitmap image with rounded corners with stroke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473113/bitmap-image-with-rounded-corners-with-stroke/14473235#14473235)

Comment: Sir, thanks for the help, its deeply appreciated... 
bt, I got what I needed from @VendettaDroid...