# Rounded corner texture bitmap in Android

Tags: android, xml

Looking for examples I am not able to found the solution. I am trying to put rounded corners to my bitmap. How can I do this in the XML? The current code of my bitmap is:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/tab_texture_image"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:dither="true" />
```

Comment: The code of your bitmap is...?

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that it was probably in your question but was hidden because of formatting. Was finding ways to make my code-block edit have enough characters changed to be allowed when I saw you'd fixed it.

Comment: Maybe can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473113/bitmap-image-with-rounded-corners-with-stroke.