# Android setting one end folded corner

Tags: android, android-layout

i have taken a layout like this having the designed background image
[image]

i need a suggestion which is the best approach either using background image or rounded corner at one end XML

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/test_back"
    android:padding="10dp">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i have attached some links, Please go through it, If you have any doubt let me know.

If you want to add rounded corner to any kind of android view like `linear layout, relative layout, button etc.`, follow the below links which i have attached.

keep this `drawable as background` for the view to which you want to `keep rounded corner border`. Let’s keep it for a LinearLayout.

[**Rounded Corner Reference1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners)

[**Rounded Corner Reference2**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473113/bitmap-image-with-rounded-corners-with-stroke)

[**Rounded Corner Reference3**](http://tips.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-layout-rounded-corner-border/)