# How to set Corner in Drawable at runtime?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I would like edit the background of layout in runtime. My image drawable is in the class and I would like to set the image with corners like background of the layout. How to do this?

Comment: post the code please.

Comment: I like to knows the code I must write.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517434/changing-image-as-rounded-corner

Answer (score 4):

1. First get the background from your view using **getBackground()**.
2. **Cast it** to a GradientDrawable variable.
3. Finally call method **setCornerRadius(float value)** with the value.

**setCornerRadius(float value)** will set all four corners with the same value.

So it also has the method setCornerRadii(float []radii), which can be used to set corners of all four sides, from top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left;

***setCornerRadii(float []radii)***

> Specify radii for each of the 4 corners. For each corner, the array contains 2 values, [X_radius, Y_radius]. The corners are ordered top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left. This property is honored only when the shape is of type RECTANGLE.

```
GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) view.getBackground();
drawable.setCornerRadii(radii);
```

**OR**

```
float values[] = {1.1f, 2.2f, 1.5f, 3.3f};
GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) view.getBackground();
drawable.setCornerRadii(values);
```

This means, top-left corner is 1.1f, top-right corner is 2.2, bottom-right corner is 1.5f and finally bottom-left corner is 3.3f.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
GradientDrawable bg = (GradientDrawable) relative_layout.getBackground();
bg.setCornerRadii();
```

Comment: How I get the relativeLayout background if I want set to relativeLayout background?

Comment: do u want to set background or you want to set rounded corners to the background?

Comment: The 2. A image of background with rounded corners :)

Comment: add this line before the two lines
`relativeLayout.setBackground("bcakground Image");`

Comment: I don't understand, the GradientDrawable have no connection with the background of relativeLayout, is a other variable, other source, other all!

Comment: type casting is necessary to use setCornerRadii method

Comment: besides:java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable

Comment: I try: 

RelativeLayout.setBackground(receita.foto);

 GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) RelativeLayout.getBackground();

        drawable.setCornerRadius(5);

       RelativeLayout.setBackground(drawable);

Comment: for bitmap, you can go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012556/border-over-a-bitmap-with-rounded-corners-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Create drawables resource for your normal and curved background and place them in `res/drawable/` folder.

For example:

**box.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
</shape>
```

**box_curved.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Then at runtime, change background by :

```
view.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.box));
```

or

```
view.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.box_curved));
```

Comment: he wants to set corners of drawable at runtime not to change drawable at runtime my friend.

Comment: I believe that too will follow the same logic, just that he needs to use an ImageView with background set dynamically like I said, and src set to the image drawable.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
> if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
>     setBackgroundDrawable();
> } else {
>     setBackground();
> }
> ```

see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11947755/3329488

Answer (score 0):

To create Shape Drawable Programetically

```
public static void createShapeDrawable(View v, int backgroundColor, int borderColor)
    {
        GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
        shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        shape.setCornerRadii(new float[] { 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0 }); // set corner Radious 
        shape.setColor(backgroundColor);
        shape.setStroke(3, borderColor);
        v.setBackgroundDrawable(shape);
    }
```