# ImageView rounded corners

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview, rounded-corners

I wanted image to have rounded corners. I implement this xml code and use this in my image view. but image overlap the shape. I am downloading the image through async task.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle" >
 <corners android:radius="20dip" />
</shape>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/trVouchersImage"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ash_arrow"
 />
```

Comment: There is a library which allow you to do that easily.
[Here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: Important note: You need to use shape as image src and original image as background image. that's the trick.

Comment: You can use this library
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I use Universal Image loader library to download and round the corners of image, and it worked for me.

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(thisContext)
            // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
           .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
           .build();

DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(10)) //rounded corner bitmap
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .build();

ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(config);
imageLoader.displayImage(image_url,image_view, options );
```

Comment: notice that `RoundedBitmapDisplayer` will give you OOM exception.

Answer (score 38):

**SIMPLEST APPROACH:**

Create an xml file ***rounded_fg.xml*** under ***res/drawable/*** folder of your app. The content of ***rounded_fg.xml*** is as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="1"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <gradient
        android:type="radial"
        android:gradientRadius="8dp"
        android:endColor="@color/white"
       />
</shape>
```

You can ***match endColor with ImageView container layout background*** & *gradientRadius may be any value as per your requirements* (<=36dp).

Now use this drawable as ***foreground*** for your imageview as follows,

```
 <ImageView
     android:layout_width="55dp"
     android:layout_height="55dp" 
     android:foreground="@drawable/rounded_fg" />
```

Works perfect with ***square images and/or imageview***.

***Square Image/ImageView:***

[image: Square Image/ImageView]

***Rectangular Image/ImageView:***

[image: Rectangular Image/ImageView]

***Foreground applied over a button:***

[image: Foreground applied over a button]

Comment: how to make Rectangular, can you give a sample?

Comment: If ImageView layout height & width are not same then you'll get a rectangular view as shown in pic above. This technique won't give perfectly rounded corners for rectangular view. It's best with square view. That's why I have given the comparison. If it's fine for you then go for it.

Comment: can we use this for rectangular view with rounded corners? @Nihal

Comment: @ParthAnjaria You can use it. You can look at the sample image in the post to get a feel of how it appears.

Comment: not able to get the exact value, can you add details here

Comment: @ParthAnjaria What values you are talking about? Nothing will change in the drawable rounded_fg.xml file. Only the container view dimensions (width & height) will change.

Comment: Note that this requires API 23

Answer (score 16):

you can do by XML like this way

```
<stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#ff000000"/>

<padding android:left="1dp"
         android:top="1dp"
         android:right="1dp"
         android:bottom="1dp"/> 

<corners android:radius="30px"/>
```

and pragmatically you can create rounded bitmap and set in ImageView.

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
    bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

final int color = 0xff424242;
final Paint paint = new Paint();
final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
final float roundPx = 12;

paint.setAntiAlias(true);
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
paint.setColor(color);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

return output;
}
```

For **Universal lazy loader** you can use this wat also.

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(25)) // default
        .build();
```

Comment: I try second code but the problem is that i download the image and then save it in bitmap, then i round the bitmap and set bitmap for image view.  Image view is part of table layout.At first install it did not round the image. but after that it works. why its not working for 1st time?

Comment: are you using UniversalImageLoader library?

Comment: i include library but dont know which method to use to round corners

Comment: if yes than you can set radius in using that library. and if any other library than you are just displaying it as rounded. so convert bitmap first than save it as cache in SDCard.

Answer (score 16):

Now we no need to use any third party lib or custom `imageView`

## Now We can use [**`ShapeableImageView`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/imageview/ShapeableImageView.java)

> SAMPLE CODE
>
> First add below `dependencies` in your **`build.gradle`** file

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'
```

### Make ImageView Circular from coding

Add `ShapeableImageView` in your layout

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    android:id="@+id/myShapeableImageView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/nilesh" />
```

Kotlin code to make ImageView Circle

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.shape.CornerFamily
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


//        <dimen name="image_corner_radius">50dp</dimen>

        val radius = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.image_corner_radius)
        myShapeableImageView.shapeAppearanceModel = myShapeableImageView.shapeAppearanceModel
            .toBuilder()
            .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radius)
            .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radius)
            .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radius)
            .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radius)
            .build()

            // or  You can use setAllCorners() method

        myShapeableImageView.shapeAppearanceModel = myShapeableImageView.shapeAppearanceModel
            .toBuilder()
            .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radius)
            .build()


    }
}
```

OUTPUT

[image]

### Make ImageView Circle from using a style

First, create a below style in your `style.xml`

```
<style name="circleImageViewStyle" >
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

Now use that style in your layout like this

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    android:id="@+id/myShapeableImageView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/circleImageViewStyle"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/nilesh" />
```

OUTPUT

[image]

> ### Please find the complete exmaple here [how to use ShapeableImageView](https://github.com/askNilesh/circular-Imageview)

Answer (score 12):

**NEW ANSWER**
Use Glide library for this. This lib is also recommended by Google. See [How to round an image with Glide library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278821/how-to-round-an-image-with-glide-library)

**OLD ANSWER**
Just add that image in a `cardView` and set cardView's elevation on 0dp...will do the trick (in my case was a `viewPager` with images - just replace the `viewPager` with an `ImageView`):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Wow, i'm surprised that this worked! I wonder how does performance-wise

Comment: I think it should work for pre-lollipop as well, because you use the v7 compat lib

Comment: You need to define `app:contentPadding="0dp"` in the `CardView`. Otherwise, it will have default padding.

Comment: @Marchy - now I would suggest to use Glide library(also recommended by Google) for achieving this effect. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278821/how-to-round-an-image-with-glide-library

Answer (score 9):

You should use `RoundedCornersTransformation` from [this library](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations) and create a circular `ImageView`.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation;

public class RoundedCornersTransformation implements Transformation {

    public enum CornerType {
        ALL,
        TOP_LEFT, TOP_RIGHT, BOTTOM_LEFT, BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT,
        OTHER_TOP_LEFT, OTHER_TOP_RIGHT, OTHER_BOTTOM_LEFT, OTHER_BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_LEFT, DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_RIGHT
    }

    private int mRadius;
    private int mDiameter;
    private int mMargin;
    private CornerType mCornerType;

    public RoundedCornersTransformation(int radius, int margin) {
        this(radius, margin, CornerType.ALL);
    }

    public RoundedCornersTransformation(int radius, int margin, CornerType cornerType) {
        mRadius = radius;
        mDiameter = radius * 2;
        mMargin = margin;
        mCornerType = cornerType;
    }

    @Override public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int width = source.getWidth();
        int height = source.getHeight();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(source, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
        drawRoundRect(canvas, paint, width, height);
        source.recycle();
        return bitmap;
    }

    private void drawRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float width, float height) {
        float right = width - mMargin;
        float bottom = height - mMargin;
        switch (mCornerType) {
            case ALL:
                canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
            break;
            case TOP_LEFT:
                drawTopLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
            break;
            case TOP_RIGHT:
                drawTopRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
            break;
            case BOTTOM_LEFT:
                drawBottomLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
            break;
            case BOTTOM_RIGHT:
                drawBottomRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
            break;
            case TOP:
                drawTopRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
            break;
            case BOTTOM:
                drawBottomRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
            break;
            case LEFT:
                drawLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
            break;
            case RIGHT:
                drawRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
            break;
            case OTHER_TOP_LEFT:
                drawOtherTopLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
            break;
            case OTHER_TOP_RIGHT:
                drawOtherTopRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
            break;
            case OTHER_BOTTOM_LEFT:
                drawOtherBottomLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
            break;
            case OTHER_BOTTOM_RIGHT:
                drawOtherBottomRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
            break;
            case DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_LEFT:
                drawDiagonalFromTopLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
            break;
            case DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_RIGHT:
                drawDiagonalFromTopRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
            break;
            default:
                canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
            break;
        }
    }

    private void drawTopLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin + mRadius, mMargin + mRadius, bottom), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawTopRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(right - mRadius, mMargin + mRadius, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawBottomLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom - mRadius), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawBottomRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(right - mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawTopRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin + mRadius, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawBottomRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawOtherTopLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawOtherTopRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawOtherBottomLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin + mRadius, right - mRadius, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawOtherBottomRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin + mRadius, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawDiagonalFromTopLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin + mRadius, right - mDiameter, bottom), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mDiameter, mMargin, right, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawDiagonalFromTopRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom - mRadius), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin + mRadius, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    @Override public String key() {
        return "RoundedTransformation(radius=" + mRadius + ", margin=" + mMargin + ", diameter=" + mDiameter + ", cornerType=" + mCornerType.name() + ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: I require the image to be in a circle? what should be the values of corners in that case?

Comment: This will round the background, but the image inside the imageView is still rectangular. not the suitable answer.

Comment: This merely sets a background with rounded corners...if you remove the colors and the padding, the image isn't altered.

Answer (score 4):

- May be you have found your solution but recently i found new library which allows you to create any many shape you want to set to the **Image VIew**.

  - Download the library from [here](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView)
  - Define your **Xml** as :-
  - `<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView......... app:riv_corner_radius="Yourradiusdip"/>`
  - And enjoy the coding.! this library i found is the best! thanks
    [I posted this answer later on but i recently used it and found it realy helpful]

Answer (score 3):

Just wondering if anyone still needs it to be done.

For them: you can use `RoundedBitmapDrawable` for your purpose.

Sample Code:

```
ImageView profilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.idimageView);

RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(this.getResources(),bitmap);
roundedBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
profilePic.setImageDrawable(roundedBitmapDrawable);
```

where `bitmap` is the image you want to load in imageView.

Answer (score 3):

Create a Drawable XML file

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="8dp" />
       <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/md_white_1000" />
```

In your layout you add the drawable as a background on the imageView.

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/photo"
        android:background="@drawable/roundcorners"/>
```

Then you add this line in your Java code.

```
ImageView.setClipToOutline(true);
```

Note: this only works with level 21+

Answer (score 2):

here is something I found from here: [github](https://gist.github.com/Pretz/1586565)

made a little improvising. Very simple and clean. No external files or methods:

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {


private float mCornerRadius = 10.0f;

public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
    super(context, attributes);
}



@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Round some corners betch!
    Drawable myDrawable = getDrawable();

    if (myDrawable!=null && myDrawable instanceof BitmapDrawable && mCornerRadius > 0) {
        Paint paint = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getPaint();
        final int color = 0xff000000;
        Rect bitmapBounds = myDrawable.getBounds();
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(bitmapBounds);
        // Create an off-screen bitmap to the PorterDuff alpha blending to work right
        int saveCount = canvas.saveLayer(rectF, null,
                Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG |
                Canvas.CLIP_SAVE_FLAG |
                Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG |
                Canvas.FULL_COLOR_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG |
                Canvas.CLIP_TO_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
        // Resize the rounded rect we'll clip by this view's current bounds
        // (super.onDraw() will do something similar with the drawable to draw)
        getImageMatrix().mapRect(rectF);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, paint);

        Xfermode oldMode = paint.getXfermode();
        // This is the paint already associated with the BitmapDrawable that super draws
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setXfermode(oldMode);
        canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
    } else {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

its simple as possible by using this util method

```
/*
 * param@ imageView is your image you want to bordered it
 */
public static Bitmap generateBorders(ImageView imageView){
    Bitmap mbitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    Bitmap imageRounded = Bitmap.createBitmap(mbitmap.getWidth(), mbitmap.getHeight(), mbitmap.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(imageRounded);
    Paint mpaint = new Paint();
    mpaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mpaint.setShader(new BitmapShader(mbitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
    canvas.drawRoundRect((new RectF(0, 0, mbitmap.getWidth(), mbitmap.getHeight())), 100, 100, mpaint);// Round Image Corner 100 100 100 100
    return imageRounded;
}
```

then set your image view bitmap with returned value have fun

Answer (score 1):

Your `MainActivity.java` is like this:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
```

You should to first get your image from Resource as `Bitmap` or `Drawable`.

If get as `Bitmap`:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ash_arrow);
bm = new Newreza().setEffect(bm, 0.2f, ((ColorDrawable) ll.getBackground).getColor);
iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Or if get as `Drawable`:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ash_arrow);
d = new Newreza().setEffect(d, 0.2f, ((ColorDrawable) ll.getBackground).getColor);
iv.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Then create new file as `Newreza.java` near `MainActivity.java`, and copy bottom codes in `Newreza.java`:

```
package your.package.name;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
//Telegram:@newreza
//mail:newreza7@gmail.com
public class Newreza{
    int a,x,y;
    float bmr;
    public Bitmap setEffect(Bitmap bm,float radius,int color){
        bm=bm.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
        bmr=radius*bm.getWidth();
        for(y=0;y<bmr;y++){
            a=(int)(bmr-Math.sqrt(y*(2*bmr-y)));
            for(x=0;x<a;x++){
                bm.setPixel(x,y,color);
            }
        }
        for(y=0;y<bmr;y++){
            a=(int)(bm.getWidth()-bmr+Math.sqrt(y*(2*bmr-y)));
            for(x=a;x<bm.getWidth();x++){
                bm.setPixel(x,y,color);
            }
        }
        for(y=(int)(bm.getHeight()-bmr);y<bm.getHeight();y++){
            a=(int)(bm.getWidth()-bmr+Math.sqrt(Math.pow(bmr,2)-Math.pow(bmr+y-bm.getHeight(),2)));
            for(x=a;x<bm.getWidth();x++){
                bm.setPixel(x,y,color);
            }
        }
        for(y=(int)(bm.getHeight()-bmr);y<bm.getHeight();y++){
            a=(int)(bmr-Math.sqrt(Math.pow(bmr,2)-Math.pow(bmr+y-bm.getHeight(),2)));
            for(x=0;x<a;x++){
                bm.setPixel(x,y,color);
            }
        }
        return bm;
    }
    public Drawable setEffect(Drawable d,float radius,int color){
        return new BitmapDrawable(Resources.getSystem(),setEffect(((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap(),radius,color));
    }
}
```

Just notice that replace your package name with first line in the code.

It %100 works, because is written in details :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this if you need to get rounded image ..

Your MainActivity.java class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private ImageView imageView;
    Bitmap roundedBitmapImage;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result);

    }

    public void pickImage(View View) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)


            try {
                // We need to recycle unused bitmaps
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }
                InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                        data.getData());
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                stream.close();

               /* Bitmap bitmap1=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                Bitmap bitmap2=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                Bitmap resultingImage=Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 480, bitmap1.getConfig());

                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultingImage);

                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                Path path=new Path();
                path.lineTo(150, 0);
                path.lineTo(230, 120);
                path.lineTo(70, 120);
                path.lineTo(150, 0);

                canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

                paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 0, 0, paint);*/

               //-------> compositeImageView.setImageBitmap(resultingImage);

                // Use this when to provide any shape to image i.e Fit image to any shape.
                // under mentioned taking reference from Rounder class. Finally changing image in round shape.
                // Here we are passing reference  bitmap.
                roundedBitmapImage = new  Rounder().getRoundedShape(bitmap);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(roundedBitmapImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

And your rounder class ..

/** This class crops image to round shape */

```
public class Rounder {
    public Bitmap getRoundedShape(Bitmap scaleBitmapImage) {
        int targetWidth = 125;
        int targetHeight = 125;
        Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);

        Path path = new Path();

        path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,
                ((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,
                (Math.min(((float) targetWidth), ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),
                Path.Direction.CCW);

        canvas.clipPath(path);

        Bitmap sourceBitmap = scaleBitmapImage;

        canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, new Rect(0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(),
                sourceBitmap.getHeight()), new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth,
                targetHeight), null);

        return targetBitmap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

found the easy way..
round imageview with user define radius:

http://shortcutsandroid.blogspot.in/2015/02/round-image-view-in-android.html

just add  **imageView.setRadius();**

//it will set radius for the round imageView.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Custom ImageView in Xml

```
public class RoundedCornerImageView extends ImageView {

    public RoundedCornerImageView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(ctx, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();
        Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundedCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public static Bitmap getRoundedCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius) {
        Bitmap finalBitmap;
        if (bitmap.getWidth() != radius || bitmap.getHeight() != radius)
            finalBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, radius, radius,
                    false);
        else
            finalBitmap = bitmap;
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                finalBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                finalBitmap.getHeight());

        final RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                finalBitmap.getHeight());

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
        //Set Required Radius Here
        int yourRadius = 7;
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectf, yourRadius, yourRadius, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(finalBitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use extend ImageView:

```
public class RadiusCornerImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {
    private int cornerRadiusDP = 0; // dp
    private int corner_radius_position;

    public RadiusCornerImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RadiusCornerImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RadiusCornerImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        TypedArray typeArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RadiusCornerImageView, 0, 0);
        try {
            cornerRadiusDP = typeArray.getInt(R.styleable.RadiusCornerImageView_corner_radius_dp, 0);
            corner_radius_position = typeArray.getInteger(R.styleable.RadiusCornerImageView_corner_radius_position, 0);
        } finally {
            typeArray.recycle();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float radiusPx = AndroidUtil.dpToPx(getContext(), cornerRadiusDP);
        Path clipPath = new Path();
        RectF rect = null;
        if (corner_radius_position == 0) { // all
            // round corners on all 4 angles
            rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        } else if (corner_radius_position == 1) {
            // round corners only on top left and top right
            rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight() + radiusPx);
         } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown corner_radius_position = " + corner_radius_position);
        }
        clipPath.addRoundRect(rect, radiusPx, radiusPx, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Nihal's answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/42234152/2832027 ), here is a pure XML version that gives a rectangle with rounded corners on API 24 and above. On below API 24, it will show no rounded corners.

Usage:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:foreground="@drawable/rounded_corner_mask"/>
```

*rounded_corner_mask.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:gravity="bottom|right">
        <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:width="@dimen/rounding_radius"
                android:height="@dimen/rounding_radius"
                android:viewportWidth="10.0"
                android:viewportHeight="10.0">
            <path
                android:pathData="M0,10 A10,10 0 0,0 10,0 L10,10 Z"
                android:fillColor="@color/white"/>
        </vector>
    </item>

    <item
        android:gravity="bottom|left">
        <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:width="@dimen/rounding_radius"
                android:height="@dimen/rounding_radius"
                android:viewportWidth="10.0"
                android:viewportHeight="10.0">
            <path
                android:pathData="M0,0 A10,10 0 0,0 10,10 L0,10 Z"
                android:fillColor="@color/white"/>
        </vector>
    </item>

    <item
        android:gravity="top|left">
        <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:width="@dimen/rounding_radius"
                android:height="@dimen/rounding_radius"
                android:viewportWidth="10.0"
                android:viewportHeight="10.0">
            <path
                android:pathData="M10,0 A10,10 0 0,0 0,10 L0,0 Z"
                android:fillColor="@color/white"/>
        </vector>
    </item>

    <item
        android:gravity="top|right">
        <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:width="@dimen/rounding_radius"
                android:height="@dimen/rounding_radius"
                android:viewportWidth="10.0"
                android:viewportHeight="10.0">
            <path
                android:pathData="M10,10 A10,10 0 0,0 0,0 L10,0 Z"
                android:fillColor="@color/white"/>
        </vector>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```