# Options to put corners in Android ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I'm trying to put corners im my ImageView and I find these "workarounds":

1 - Take the Bitmap soure and paint then

2 - put a second ImageView on my layout and use shape+corners as its source

It's not possible take the image view and put a corner around then?

In my app i have a List with a lot of ImageView (the Bitmap used in this ImageView's is programmatically) and I want to put corners in every ImageView.

There is any other option?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `selector` that contains `shape` with rounded corners, and then apply it as the `ImageView`'s background using xml.

Look at this answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743859/imageview-rounded-corners)

You can also do it via code by using `PorterDuffXfermode`. `PorterDuffXfermode` uses alpha compositing that will allow you to create and intersection (things of mathematical sets here) between the `Canvas` you get from `onDraw()` and an off screen `Canvas` you will have to create. You will use one of the `PorterDuff.Mode` flags to tell the framework you want to only render the pixels that intersect from the two `Bitmaps` in each `Canvas`.

More on [Alpha Compositing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing)

Comment: And how can i retriever this selector programmatically and set a BMP as its drawable resource?

Comment: You will not retrieve the selector, you will set it as the `background` of the `ImageView` and then add the `Bitmap` to the `ImageView` via code.