# How to Increase Speed of Android Studio Application Builds?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there any way to display which process of my build is the one taking the most time and then try and work around it?

I am using Android Studio. I wouldn't call my project big at the moment but I guess the dependencies I require makes it larger and the build still takes between 40-60 seconds. (down from 90 seconds before removing multi dex)

Here are my Mid 2015 Macbook Pro's specs:

- Processor: 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7
- Memory: 16GB 1600 MHz DDR3

I have had to remove part of a dependency to be able to build without enabling multi dex support and this saved me ~20 seconds, however I want to add more dependencies so I need to improve my build time so I can then re-enable multi dex and actually use the dependencies I want to.

I have seen a few posts about modifying Android Studio to speed up the build time but these don't seem to have worked and I would rather see if I could fix the cause.

Here are my current dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

// MY INTERNAL LIBRARIES
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile project(':ViewPagerIndicator')
    compile project(':connection-manager')
    compile project(':core-library')
    compile project(':activity-manager')
    compile project(':activity-recorder')

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
    compile 'com.androidplot:androidplot-core:0.6.1'

    compile project(':ParseLoginUI')

    /*Images*/
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.1.0' // https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'

//    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have inadvertently fixed the issue I was seeing my end whilst working on other things.

Implementing the external dependency `Retrolambda` was increasing my build time from ~10 seconds to ~45/50 seconds. Removing this from my application decreased it significantly (by ~40 seconds in fact!).

I removed `retrolambda` because I wanted to start testing my application and needed the dependencies `Robolectric` and `Mockito`. If I used `retrolambda` at the same time I got an exception along the lines of `unsupported major.minor version` pointing at `JDK 7`. The long and short of the story is I was fed up of hacking around my dependencies and build setup just to use `retrolambda` (Android Studio mimics them anyway in it's code folding).

Answer (score 6):

There are two main things you can do improve building speed:

1. Offline work:

[image: offline work on gradle]

2. Compile against bigger SDK versions:

This one is tricky. Usually your `minSdkVersion` needs to be something like 14 or 16. This slow things down. If you compile using `minSdkVerison = 22` speed times increase dramatically.
You can increase `minSdkVersion` during development and reduce it when release.

Comment: Setting `Offline work` is a hit. However, you must remember to set it off again if you add any dependency

Comment: I'm afraid on average these methods don't save me any time. Perhaps the offline works but for a negligible 3/4 secs. The minSDK trick didn't seem to have any effect

Comment: Other thing you can do is try to play with DexOptions:

`dexOptions {
        incremental = false
        preDexLibraries = false
    }`
There is more info here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Advanced-Build-Customization

Answer (score 1):

Using offline mode for gradle can improve build times.

```
Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Offline work
```

The downside is that you have to turn off offline mode whenever dependencies are updated.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work. I perhaps saved ~3/4 seconds per build.

Answer (score 0):

You could also replace two libraries (picasso and round image view) with Glide and a utility class that will easily do the job of roundimageview library.

Check this post for an example code that transforms image to a rounded one with glide. [How to round an image with Glide library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278821/how-do-rounded-image-with-glide-library/25806229#25806229)

I'll also suggest you to create Utility directory and place this CircleTransform class into it.

Doing steps above will reduce number of libraries that you use and hence the **method count** and **build time of your project!**