# How to make border for circle cropped image in glide

Tags: android, android-glide

in default, the image that is cropped by glide has no border I need to have a border in the circle image.

Comment: I think you need this [How do rounded image with Glide library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278821/how-do-rounded-image-with-glide-library)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[image]

**With compose**

Remember to add dependencies to build.gradle:

```
implementation ‘androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.0-beta02’
```

In your activity

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ShapeImageApplicationTheme {
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    RoundedCornerShapeDemo()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RoundedCornerShapeDemo() {
    ImageResource(shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
}

@Composable
fun ImageResource(shape: Shape) {
    ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val (redBox, imageBox) = createRefs()
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .clip(shape)
                .background(Color.Red)
                .constrainAs(redBox) {})

        val image: Painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
        Image(painter = image, contentDescription = "", modifier = Modifier
            .size(90.dp)
            .clip(shape)
            .constrainAs(imageBox) {
                top.linkTo(redBox.top)
                start.linkTo(redBox.start)
                end.linkTo(redBox.end)
                bottom.linkTo(redBox.bottom)
            })
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    ShapeImageApplicationTheme {
        RoundedCornerShapeDemo()
    }
}
```

**Version 4**

I made this way, RoundedCorners Class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.Transformation;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.Resource;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.bitmap_recycle.BitmapPool;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.BitmapResource;

import java.security.MessageDigest;



public class RoundedCornersTransformation implements Transformation<Bitmap> {

    public enum CornerType {
        ALL,
        TOP_LEFT, TOP_RIGHT, BOTTOM_LEFT, BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT,
        OTHER_TOP_LEFT, OTHER_TOP_RIGHT, OTHER_BOTTOM_LEFT, OTHER_BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_LEFT, DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_RIGHT, BORDER
    }

    private BitmapPool mBitmapPool;
    private int mRadius;
    private int mDiameter;
    private int mMargin;
    private CornerType mCornerType;
    private String mColor;
    private int mBorder;

    public RoundedCornersTransformation(Context context, int radius, int margin) {
        this(context, radius, margin, CornerType.ALL);
    }

    public RoundedCornersTransformation(Context context, int radius, int margin, String color, int border) {
        this(context, radius, margin, CornerType.BORDER);
        mColor = color;
        mBorder = border;
    }

    public RoundedCornersTransformation(BitmapPool pool, int radius, int margin) {
        this(pool, radius, margin, CornerType.ALL);
    }

    public RoundedCornersTransformation(Context context, int radius, int margin,
                                        CornerType cornerType) {
        this(Glide.get(context).getBitmapPool(), radius, margin, cornerType);
    }

    public RoundedCornersTransformation(BitmapPool pool, int radius, int margin,
                                        CornerType cornerType) {
        mBitmapPool = pool;
        mRadius = radius;
        mDiameter = mRadius * 2;
        mMargin = margin;
        mCornerType = cornerType;
    }

    @Override
    public Resource<Bitmap> transform(Context context, Resource<Bitmap> resource, int outWidth, int outHeight) {
        Bitmap source = resource.get();

        int width = source.getWidth();
        int height = source.getHeight();

        Bitmap bitmap = mBitmapPool.get(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        if (bitmap == null) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(source, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
        drawRoundRect(canvas, paint, width, height);
        return BitmapResource.obtain(bitmap, mBitmapPool);
    }

    private void drawRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float width, float height) {
        float right = width - mMargin;
        float bottom = height - mMargin;

        switch (mCornerType) {
            case ALL:
                canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
                break;
            case TOP_LEFT:
                drawTopLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case TOP_RIGHT:
                drawTopRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case BOTTOM_LEFT:
                drawBottomLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case BOTTOM_RIGHT:
                drawBottomRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case TOP:
                drawTopRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case BOTTOM:
                drawBottomRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case LEFT:
                drawLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                drawRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case OTHER_TOP_LEFT:
                drawOtherTopLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case OTHER_TOP_RIGHT:
                drawOtherTopRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case OTHER_BOTTOM_LEFT:
                drawOtherBottomLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case OTHER_BOTTOM_RIGHT:
                drawOtherBottomRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_LEFT:
                drawDiagonalFromTopLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_RIGHT:
                drawDiagonalFromTopRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case BORDER:
                drawBorder(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            default:
                canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void drawTopLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, mMargin + mDiameter),
                mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin + mRadius, mMargin + mRadius, bottom), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawTopRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius,
                mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(right - mRadius, mMargin + mRadius, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawBottomLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom),
                mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom - mRadius), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawBottomRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius,
                mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(right - mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawTopRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin + mRadius, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawBottomRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawOtherTopLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawOtherTopRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawOtherBottomLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin + mRadius, right - mRadius, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawOtherBottomRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right,
                                               float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin + mRadius, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawDiagonalFromTopLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right,
                                                  float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, mMargin + mDiameter),
                mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius,
                mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin + mRadius, right - mDiameter, bottom), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mDiameter, mMargin, right, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawDiagonalFromTopRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right,
                                                   float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius,
                mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom),
                mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom - mRadius), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin + mRadius, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawBorder(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right,
                            float bottom) {

        // stroke
        Paint strokePaint = new Paint();
        strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        if (mColor != null) {
            strokePaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(mColor));
        } else {
            strokePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        strokePaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorder);

        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);

        // stroke
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, strokePaint);
    }


    @Override
    public void updateDiskCacheKey(MessageDigest messageDigest) {

    }

    public String getId() {
        return "RoundedTransformation(radius=" + mRadius + ", margin=" + mMargin + ", diameter="
                + mDiameter + ", cornerType=" + mCornerType.name() + ")";
    }
}
```

Now in your Activity, you have to put this:

```
public static int sCorner = 15;
public static int sMargin = 2;
public static int sBorder = 10;
public static String sColor = "#7D9067";


    ...

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_image_view);


    ImageView mImageViewBorder = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_image_view_border);


     ....
            // Rounded corners
        Glide.with(this).load("http://scareface.jpeg")
        .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(
        new RoundedCornersTransformation(this, sCorner, sMargin))).into(mImageView);
        
        // Rounded corners with border
        Glide.with(this).load("http://scareface.jpeg")
        .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(
        new RoundedCornersTransformation(this, sCorner, sMargin, sColor, sBorder))).into(mImageViewBorder);
```

You can check my example in [github](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/RoundedConersWithGlide).

Also you can check this [post](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/rounded-coners-with-glide/) and this [library](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations) for **Version 3**.

Comment: originally from here.. i guess 
https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations

Comment: Which is your problem? Can I help? @ShajeelAfzal

Comment: @Cabezas, I have followed your answer but it didn't worked.

Comment: @Cabezas ..How to create the border around the  rectangle.. Do you have any idea about it?? Thanks..

Comment: you should read [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html), you can see two methods: drawRect and drawRoundRect.

Comment: @Cabezas .. Could u please help me to create the border of the imageview using the glide

Comment: you can modify the RoundedCornersTransformation class... What do you need exactly?

Comment: RoundedCornersTransformation with DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_LEFT is not working as expected

Comment: @Cabezas Why did you set color as a string? Also, does it do center-crop, or should I add it too (if I wish) ? If it doesn't do it, how can I add center-crop ? Just call `apply` twice, while the first one is `.apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform())` ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper you can make [a RequestOptions object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47265517/using-requestoptions-in-appglidemodule-with-glide-4). If you don't like color as a string, you can convert this line `strokePaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(mColor));` to this line  `strokePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);`

Comment: Yes, this works fine. However, I've noticed that if I choose to have a 1dp stroke width, it is being cut a bit on the right side. How come? BTW, you have a typo : "Coners" instead of "Corners"

Comment: I don't know why this is become the accepted answer, but it different with the question/requirement which is **circle**, not **rounded rectangle**. This https://stackoverflow.com/a/53606048/3940133 fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 35):

Based on @wadali's answer to making it work for **Glide 4.x** and **Kotlin** programming language. I also optimized the code a little bit, so it is cleaner, you can change the color directly and also leveraging the Kotlin extension function. It's not rounded corner like the accepted answer but fully circle like the sample image below.

[image: image result]

Add this code to your project

```kotlin
import android.graphics.*
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.core.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.BitmapImageViewTarget

/**
 * Load model into ImageView as a circle image with borderSize (optional) using Glide
 *
 * @param model - Any object supported by Glide (Uri, File, Bitmap, String, resource id as Int, ByteArray, and Drawable)
 * @param borderSize - The border size in pixel
 * @param borderColor - The border color
 */
fun <T> ImageView.loadCircularImage(
    model: T,
    borderSize: Float = 0F,
    borderColor: Int = Color.WHITE
) {
    Glide.with(context)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(model)
        .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
        .into(object : BitmapImageViewTarget(this) {
            override fun setResource(resource: Bitmap?) {
                setImageDrawable(
                    resource?.run {
                        RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(
                            resources,
                            if (borderSize > 0) {
                                createBitmapWithBorder(borderSize, borderColor)
                            } else {
                                this
                            }
                        ).apply {
                            isCircular = true
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        })
}

/**
 * Create a new bordered bitmap with the specified borderSize and borderColor
 *
 * @param borderSize - The border size in pixel
 * @param borderColor - The border color
 * @return A new bordered bitmap with the specified borderSize and borderColor
 */
private fun Bitmap.createBitmapWithBorder(borderSize: Float, borderColor: Int): Bitmap {
    val borderOffset = (borderSize * 2).toInt()
    val halfWidth = width / 2
    val halfHeight = height / 2
    val circleRadius = Math.min(halfWidth, halfHeight).toFloat()
    val newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        width + borderOffset,
        height + borderOffset,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )

    // Center coordinates of the image
    val centerX = halfWidth + borderSize
    val centerY = halfHeight + borderSize

    val paint = Paint()
    val canvas = Canvas(newBitmap).apply {
        // Set transparent initial area
        drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
    }

    // Draw the transparent initial area
    paint.isAntiAlias = true
    paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, circleRadius, paint)

    // Draw the image
    paint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    canvas.drawBitmap(this, borderSize, borderSize, paint)

    // Draw the createBitmapWithBorder
    paint.xfermode = null
    paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    paint.color = borderColor
    paint.strokeWidth = borderSize
    canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, circleRadius, paint)
    return newBitmap
}
```

And use it

```kotlin
yourImageView.loadCircularImage(
        imageUrl, // or any object supported by Glide
        borderSizeInPx, // default is 0. If you don't change it, then the image will have no border
        Color.RED // optional, default is white
)
```

Comment: Best answer for kotlin by far. Code is nice !

Comment: Can you be more specific @dcdrns ? I tried on Genymotion API Level 23 with minSdkVersion 23 is working fine. Please make sure you have internet permission and the image you load is not huge

Comment: it seems that the bordersize crops away the underlying image. Is it possible to add the circle around the image and not on the image?

Answer (score 28):

Drawable for Circle border of ImageView circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/et_thick"
        android:color="@color/profile_pic_round" />

    <corners android:radius="@dimen/default_corner_radius" />

</shape>
```

and layout will be like this

Make sure your ImageView height and width lower then RelativeLayout height and width

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle">// set circle drawable here

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="145dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and set Image with circuler programetically like this

```
Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(imagePath)//<= path of image
            .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransform(mContext))//<= For Circuler image
            .into(ivProfileImage);//<= your Imageview
```

Comment: you should add `compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'` to gradle for `CropCircleTransform`

Comment: But RelativeLayout is expensive

Comment: Then use FrameLayout

Comment: For me, the border was too thin. I had to put `android:padding="2dp"` in RelativeLayout to get the border width i desired.

Answer (score 10):

**Good way to do this thing without using any outer layout**

```
public static <T> void circleImage(final ImageView imageView, T uri, final boolean border) {
    Glide.with(imageView.getContext()).load(uri).asBitmap().centerCrop().into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(imageView) {
        @Override
        protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
            RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(imageView.getContext().getResources(), border ? addWhiteBorder(resource, imageView.getContext()) : resource);
            circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
        }
    });
}
```

For Adding border with bitmap

```
private static Bitmap addBorder(Bitmap resource, Context context) {
    int w = resource.getWidth();
    int h = resource.getHeight();
    int radius = Math.min(h / 2, w / 2);
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(w + 8, h + 8, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(output);
    c.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    c.drawCircle((w / 2) + 4, (h / 2) + 4, radius, p);
    p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    c.drawBitmap(resource, 4, 4, p);
    p.setXfermode(null);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    p.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
    p.setStrokeWidth(3);
    c.drawCircle((w / 2) + 4, (h / 2) + 4, radius, p);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Wow, big +1 dude

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53606048/3940133 is the updated answer for Glide 4.x and kotlin

Answer (score 2):

**It's easy with an outer layout:**

your_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_border_style">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

res/drawable/round_border_style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape>
        <gradient android:angle="0" android:endColor="@color/white" android:startColor="@color/white" android:centerColor="@color/white" android:gradientRadius="10sp" />
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <stroke android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/gray"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Controller.java

```
GlideApp.with(context).load(url).fitCenter().into(imageView);
```