# glide rounded corner transform issue

Tags: android

i use the following code to load an image with rounded corners into imageview using glide:

```
Glide.with(this)
                .load(url)
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .transition(withCrossFade())
                .apply(new RequestOptions().transform(new RoundedCorners(50)).error(R.drawable.default_person).skipMemoryCache(true).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
                .into(mBinding.profileImgv);
```

[image]
images get pixelized for some reason. Can somebody tell me where is the problem?

Comment: hi, do you solve this problem? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 100):

I had the same issue, the problem in my case was the image what i've tried to load had less size in pixels (320x480), then the ImageView size in pixels. 
My solution was the following:

My ImageView in the xml file:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_program_thumb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="186dp" />
```

ProgramViewHolder.java class

```
@BindView(R.id.image_program_thumb) ImageView mProgramThumbnail;
.....
void bindData(final Program item) {
    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions = requestOptions.transforms(new CenterCrop(), new RoundedCorners(16));
    Glide.with(itemView.getContext())
            .load(item.getImage())
            .apply(requestOptions)
            .into(mProgramThumbnail);
....
```

}

P.S. I use 4.2.0 version of Glide

Comment: Kindly remind that order of arguments in `transforms()` matters! `CenterCrop()` must be done before `RoundedCorners()`.

Comment: @androiddeveloper It should be there, please check the documentations:

https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html
https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/request/RequestOptions.html

Comment: @androiddeveloper exactly )))
If you check my above sample code that's the class i've used 

RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions = requestOptions.transforms(new CenterCrop(), new RoundedCorners(16));

Comment: Ummm... Sorry for that. I'm going to delete these stupid comments I've written, and give you +1 .

Comment: But how do you add the stroke (width+color) for the rounded corners though?  Is there one for this too?

Comment: @androiddeveloper 
If you want to add some stroke to your rounded image probably you should create a custom BitmapTransformation, explained here:
https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/transformations.html#custom-transformations

Comment: I've also created a custom BitmapTransformation class, but the most of the code was just copy-pasted from RoundedCorners.java. I've checked my custom StrokeTransformation in a sample project, and it seems works, but did not spent much time for that, so probably you may apply some more improvements for it.
So here is the gists, feel free to use and improve them :))
https://gist.github.com/mondoktamas/71d7a5b0fa9db09ed6c1e508ee178d4d
https://gist.github.com/mondoktamas/4c1e3e5a4bcb47e4c586ed0974362258

Comment: @MondokTamas Wait, the transformations create new bitmaps? I thought they wrap the bitmap into a drawable or something...

Comment: @androiddeveloper Probably not all of them, but The RoundedCorners transformation seems do.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/load/resource/bitmap/RoundedCorners.java

This class uses the TransformationUtils class, and the roundedCorners method creates a new bitmap, pls check the method documentation

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/f7d860412f061e059aa84a42f2563a01ac8c303b/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/load/resource/bitmap/TransformationUtils.java#L475

Comment: @MondokTamas Isn't it better to use a drawable then? Or maybe they cache the output of these transformations?

Comment: @androiddeveloper If you want to load an image to an ImageView you can use a BitmapDrawable, but anyway it will hold a reference to the bitmap inside. The drawable is just an abstraction of something that can be drawn on the canvas.
About the caching, i'm not really familiar how it happens on Glide, but if you setup it correctly it have to cache your bitmaps.

Comment: @MondokTamas I meant a wrapper to the Bitmap, that will draw it with center-crop, rounded corners, and stroke. About the caching, I meant that maybe Glide will cache this result inside a bitmap, so that it won't have to "transform" it again into a new bitmap, on the next time it does it. I don't think it caches it.

Comment: @androiddeveloper From my view of point it does not make sense to wrap the bitmap, as you have to make modifications with the bitmap itself (round the corners, add stroke, etc.)  Accordingly to the cache, as far as i remember Glide can be setup to cache the transformed bitmap, you just have to use the correct diskCacheStrategy. Here is some info how the cache works:
https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html#caching-in-glide

Comment: @MondokTamas I think it depends on which operations you do. As most of the operations are treated by the GPU, it should be easy for it to handle them on its own via a Drawable instead of making a new Bitmap for each operation (which might take more resources and time)

Answer (score 67):

**in Glide V4**

Try like this

```
 Glide.with(this.context)
                .load(url)
                .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(new RoundedCorners(14)))
                .into(ImageView);
```

Comment: Thank you for this issue

Comment: Only the `.apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(new RoundedCorners(14)))` line is enough to apply the corner. No need to add `.apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))`. Thanks for your answer by the way.

Comment: This is the answer but make sure in your ImageView, you MUST HAVE NOT set android:scaleType="centerCrop". Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 48):

**For Glide v4.9 transformation (java):**

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.sample)
            .transform(new CenterCrop(),new RoundedCorners(25))
            .into(image);
```

Answer (score 28):

For Glide v4.9 the following transformation works fine:

```
Glide.with(holder.imageView.context)
        .load(myDataset[position])
        .transform(CenterInside(),RoundedCorners(24))
        .into(holder.imageView)
```

[image]

Comment: Works for me v4.9

Answer (score 11):

This is what worked for me (generated API, Glide 4.9, Kotlin):

```
GlideApp.with(imageView)
    .load(pictureUri)
    .transform(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(8))
    .into(imageView)
```

Found here: https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations/issues/94

Answer (score 6):

As you can see in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49126354/2318632), it can also be achieved using [Glide's Generated API](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html). It takes some initial work but then gives you all the power of Glide with the flexibility to do anything because you write the actual code so I think it's a good solution for the long run. Plus, the usage is very simple and neat.

First, setup [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) version 4+:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
```

Then create Glide's app module class to trigger the annotation processing:

```
@GlideModule
public final class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {}
```

Then create the Glide extension which actually does the work. You can customize it to do whatever you want:

```
@GlideExtension
public class MyGlideExtension {

private MyGlideExtension() {}

    @NonNull
    @GlideOption
    public static RequestOptions roundedCorners(RequestOptions options, @NonNull Context context, int cornerRadius) {
        int px = Math.round(cornerRadius * (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
        return options.transforms(new RoundedCorners(px));
    }
}
```

After adding these files, build your project.

Then use it in your code like this:

```
GlideApp.with(this)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .roundedCorners(getApplicationContext(), 5)
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19018408)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Sree Added the essential parts of the answer.

Comment: Is it also possible to add stroke to the rounded corners output of this?

Comment: Don't forget to add a space between `RequestOptions` and `options` in params.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks @grrigore.

Answer (score 3):

on Kotlin:

```
       Glide.with(applicationContext)
            .load("YourUrl")
            .centerCrop()
            .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(RoundedCorners(12)))
            .into(imgTest)
```

Answer (score 1):

To simply add corners in **Glide version 4**, just use this simple spinnet:

```
val cornerRadius = context.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.corner_radius)

Glide.with(this)
    .asBitmap()
    .load(image)
    .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(RoundedCorners(cornerRadius)))
    .into(imageView)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work at all ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load(user.getPhotoUrl())
            .centerCrop()
            .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(new RoundedCorners(150)))//this line of code help to rounded the image to circle`enter code here`
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(userPic);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
Glide.with(context).load(url).centerCrop().into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(imageView) {
        @Override
        protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
            RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                    RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), resource);
            circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
        }
    });
```

Comment: i do not want to have a circle image view...just to add some border radius to the imageview

Comment: @tsiro which flide virsion  you using

Comment: glide:4.0.0-RC0 version

Comment: there is no asBitmap method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149576/discussion-between-tsiro-and-nilesh-rathod).

Answer (score 0):

There is a change in Sir Codesalot answer

Instead of doing this

```
GlideApp.with(this)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .roundedCorners(getApplicationContext(), 5)
            .into(imageView);
```

Do this

```
Glide.with(holder.ivBook.context)
            .load(timeline.bookImageUrl)
            .apply(MyGlideExtension.roundCorners(new RequestOptions, holder.ivBook.context, 10))
            .into(holder.ivBook)
```

`

Answer (score -1):

I've made a bit modified version of a similar solution for this ([**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36372555/878126) and [**here**](https://github.com/thedeveloperworldisyours/RoundedConersWithGlide)) , and in Kotlin .

Example of usage:

```
val borderWidth= TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1, context.resources.displayMetrics).toInt()
Glide.with(activity)
      .asBitmap()
      .load(photoUrl)
      .apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform())
      .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(RoundedCornersTransformation(activity, iconRoundedCornersRadius, 0, 0xff999999.toInt(), borderWidth)))
      .into(object : BitmapImageViewTarget(imageView) {
                                    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                                        super.onResourceReady(resource, transition)
                                        //do something if needed
                                    }
                                })
```

**RoundedCornersTransformation.kt**

```
class RoundedCornersTransformation @JvmOverloads constructor(private val bitmapPool: BitmapPool, private val radius: Int, private val margin: Int,
                                                             private val cornerType: CornerType = CornerType.ALL) : Transformation<Bitmap> {
    private val diameter: Int = radius * 2
    private var color = Color.BLACK
    private var border: Int = 0

//    val id: String
//        get() = ("RoundedTransformation(radius=" + radius + ", margin=" + margin + ", diameter="
//                + diameter + ", cornerType=" + cornerType.name + ")")

    enum class CornerType {
        ALL,
        TOP_LEFT, TOP_RIGHT, BOTTOM_LEFT, BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT,
        OTHER_TOP_LEFT, OTHER_TOP_RIGHT, OTHER_BOTTOM_LEFT, OTHER_BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_LEFT, DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_RIGHT, BORDER
    }

    constructor(context: Context, radius: Int, margin: Int, @ColorInt color: Int, border: Int) : this(context, radius, margin, CornerType.BORDER) {
        this.color = color
        this.border = border
    }

    @JvmOverloads
    constructor(context: Context, radius: Int, margin: Int,
                cornerType: CornerType = CornerType.ALL) : this(Glide.get(context).bitmapPool, radius, margin, cornerType)

    override fun transform(context: Context, resource: Resource<Bitmap>, outWidth: Int, outHeight: Int): Resource<Bitmap> {
        val source = resource.get()
        val width = source.width
        val height = source.height
        var bitmap: Bitmap? = bitmapPool.get(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        if (bitmap == null)
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap!!)
        val paint = Paint()
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
        paint.shader = BitmapShader(source, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP)
        drawRoundRect(canvas, paint, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat())
        return BitmapResource.obtain(bitmap, bitmapPool)!!
    }

    private fun drawRoundRect(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint, width: Float, height: Float) {
        val right = width - margin
        val bottom = height - margin
        when (cornerType) {
            RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.ALL -> canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), right, bottom), radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(), paint)
            RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.TOP_LEFT -> drawTopLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom)
            RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.TOP_RIGHT -> drawTopRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom)
            RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.BOTTOM_LEFT -> drawBottomLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom)
            RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.BOTTOM_RIGHT -> drawBottomRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom)
            RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.TOP -> drawTopRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom)
            RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.BOTTOM -> drawBottomRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom)
            RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.LEFT -> drawLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom)
            RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.RIGHT -> drawRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom)
            RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.OTHER_TOP_LEFT -> drawOtherTopLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom)
            RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.OTHER_TOP_RIGHT -> drawOtherTopRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom)
            RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.OTHER_BOTTOM_LEFT -> drawOtherBottomLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom)
            RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.OTHER_BOTTOM_RIGHT -> drawOtherBottomRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom)
            RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_LEFT -> drawDiagonalFromTopLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom)
            RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_RIGHT -> drawDiagonalFromTopRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom)
            RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.BORDER -> drawBorder(canvas, paint, right, bottom)
//            else -> canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), right, bottom), radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(), paint)
        }
    }

    private fun drawTopLeftRoundRect(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), (margin + diameter).toFloat(), (margin + diameter).toFloat()),
                radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(), paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), (margin + radius).toFloat(), (margin + radius).toFloat(), bottom), paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF((margin + radius).toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), right, bottom), paint)
    }

    private fun drawTopRightRoundRect(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(right - diameter, margin.toFloat(), right, (margin + diameter).toFloat()), radius.toFloat(),
                radius.toFloat(), paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), right - radius, bottom), paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF(right - radius, (margin + radius).toFloat(), right, bottom), paint)
    }

    private fun drawBottomLeftRoundRect(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), bottom - diameter, (margin + diameter).toFloat(), bottom),
                radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(), paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), (margin + diameter).toFloat(), bottom - radius), paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF((margin + radius).toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), right, bottom), paint)
    }

    private fun drawBottomRightRoundRect(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(right - diameter, bottom - diameter, right, bottom), radius.toFloat(),
                radius.toFloat(), paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), right - radius, bottom), paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF(right - radius, margin.toFloat(), right, bottom - radius), paint)
    }

    private fun drawTopRoundRect(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), right, (margin + diameter).toFloat()), radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(),
                paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), (margin + radius).toFloat(), right, bottom), paint)
    }

    private fun drawBottomRoundRect(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), bottom - diameter, right, bottom), radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(),
                paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), right, bottom - radius), paint)
    }

    private fun drawLeftRoundRect(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), (margin + diameter).toFloat(), bottom), radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(),
                paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF((margin + radius).toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), right, bottom), paint)
    }

    private fun drawRightRoundRect(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(right - diameter, margin.toFloat(), right, bottom), radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(),
                paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), right - radius, bottom), paint)
    }

    private fun drawOtherTopLeftRoundRect(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), bottom - diameter, right, bottom), radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(),
                paint)
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(right - diameter, margin.toFloat(), right, bottom), radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(),
                paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), right - radius, bottom - radius), paint)
    }

    private fun drawOtherTopRightRoundRect(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), (margin + diameter).toFloat(), bottom), radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(),
                paint)
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), bottom - diameter, right, bottom), radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(),
                paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF((margin + radius).toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), right, bottom - radius), paint)
    }

    private fun drawOtherBottomLeftRoundRect(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), right, (margin + diameter).toFloat()), radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(),
                paint)
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(right - diameter, margin.toFloat(), right, bottom), radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(),
                paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), (margin + radius).toFloat(), right - radius, bottom), paint)
    }

    private fun drawOtherBottomRightRoundRect(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), right, (margin + diameter).toFloat()), radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(),
                paint)
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), (margin + diameter).toFloat(), bottom), radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(),
                paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF((margin + radius).toFloat(), (margin + radius).toFloat(), right, bottom), paint)
    }

    private fun drawDiagonalFromTopLeftRoundRect(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), (margin + diameter).toFloat(), (margin + diameter).toFloat()),
                radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(), paint)
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(right - diameter, bottom - diameter, right, bottom), radius.toFloat(),
                radius.toFloat(), paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), (margin + radius).toFloat(), right - diameter, bottom), paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF((margin + diameter).toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), right, bottom - radius), paint)
    }

    private fun drawDiagonalFromTopRightRoundRect(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(right - diameter, margin.toFloat(), right, (margin + diameter).toFloat()), radius.toFloat(),
                radius.toFloat(), paint)
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), bottom - diameter, (margin + diameter).toFloat(), bottom),
                radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(), paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), right - radius, bottom - radius), paint)
        canvas.drawRect(RectF((margin + radius).toFloat(), (margin + radius).toFloat(), right, bottom), paint)
    }

    private fun drawBorder(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
        // stroke
        val strokePaint = Paint()
        strokePaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokePaint.color = color
        strokePaint.strokeWidth = border.toFloat()
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), right, bottom), radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(), paint)
        // stroke
        canvas.drawRoundRect(RectF(margin.toFloat(), margin.toFloat(), right, bottom), radius.toFloat(), radius.toFloat(), strokePaint)
    }


    override fun updateDiskCacheKey(messageDigest: MessageDigest) {
    }
}
```

Comment: @Itoun Why not?

Comment: The radius is not applied on the top corners

Comment: @Itoun Can you please post a sample POC to show this issue? Maybe on Github?

Answer (score -1):

```
 Glide.with(getContext())              
.setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)             
.load("URL Here")             
 .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(new RoundedCorners(14)))
.into("Your View reference")
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.