# Why glide center crop didn't work correctly?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-glide

I use

```
Glide.with(root.context)
      .load(url)
      .placeholder(R.drawable.product)
      .error(R.drawable.product)
      .centerCrop()
      .into(bindingUsersMedia.imageViewMedia)
```

and imageView code

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewMedia"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/product_placeholder" />
```

My image still look like rectangle, but i need that i need squaery(68x68)
What am I doing wrong?
*glide version - 4.11.0

Comment: Can you share what the result is like now and how you would like it to appear?

Comment: Please, check this image https://imgur.com/a/UYyqGSk

Answer (score 0):

A few questions for you:

1. Where do you want to see the desirable result? Whether from the "Design" tab in Android Studio's XML Editor or from Emulator/Physical device? As for "Design" tab keep attention to your image you use as a placeholder here:
   `tools:srcCompat="@drawable/product_placeholder"`?
   It might have some unnecessary spaces that can distort the appearance.
2. Similar question to `.load(url)`. Does it loads an appropriate image you want? Isn't it transparent like ".png" one? Pay attention to cache, as you can have the same URL address but it can pull the outdated version with the same URL.
3. Again for another one: `.error(R.drawable.product)`. What image exists behind this resource address?
4. Keep in mind that Glide will respect the view's scale type in XML as well. And the value in `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` attribute of your ImageView would lead Glide to also use `centerCrop` as a scale type, so you don't need it in your Java/Kotlin code or vice versa: you can remove it from XML and leave in your code.

Comment: I want rounded squaere in Emultaor/Physical device, my placeholder - also square image, please check https://imgur.com/a/UYyqGSk

Comment: @Student4543 to make it have the rounded corners use ".transform(CenterInside(),RoundedCorners(24))", please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57240353/7052218