# Using RequestOptions in AppGlideModule with Glide 4

Tags: java, android, android-glide, image-loading

I used the `Glide library with AppGlideModule, version of library 4.1.1. Here is my glide module class:

```
@GlideModule
public class GlideUtil extends AppGlideModule {

    private final int IMAGE_CACHE_SIZE = 20 * 1024 * 1024; // 20 MB
    private final String IMAGE_FOLDER = "/User/Images";

    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        requestOptions.format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888);
        requestOptions.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);
        builder.setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions);
        InternalCacheDiskCacheFactory factory = new InternalCacheDiskCacheFactory(context, IMAGE_FOLDER, IMAGE_CACHE_SIZE);
        builder.setDiskCache(factory);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isManifestParsingEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
```

This code worked successfully. But when i updated version of glide library to 4.3.1

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1' 
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1'
```

in GlideUtil class i saw messages: "The result of format is not used", "The result of diskCacheStrategyis not used":

[image]

So, how to resolve this? And do the methods `diskCacheStrategy` and `format` work on Glide 4.3.1 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, that you are not using the builder object, that is returned by [`format()`](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/request/RequestOptions.html#format-com.bumptech.glide.load.DecodeFormat-), thus your actions become pointless, that's why lint warns you. You can [see](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/request/RequestOptions.java#L878) that method annotated with `@CheckResult`, that's how lint understands, that you are on a wrong way, because you are *"not checking the result"* returned by that method.

Instead perform following:

```
    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions = requestOptions.format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888);
    requestOptions = requestOptions.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);
```

Now the warning would be gone.

Or you may perform following directly:

```
    builder.setDefaultRequestOptions(new RequestOptions()
                                        .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
                                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL));
```