# How to draw border on BottomNavigation MenuItem Icon?

Tags: android, navigation, android-glide, coil

I am developing an android app using:

- Jetpack Lifecycle (ViewModel)
- Jetpack Navigation
- Coil (Image Loader)

I am trying to customize the BottomNavigationMenu.

But one thing is very hard...

[image]

The last tab is the User's profile Image with Border.

If the user's profile image background color is white, then the ui is weird.
So I should show the border.

```
class MainActivity {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        initBottomNav(binding.bottomNav)
        vm.initProfileBottomIcon()
    }

    private fun initBottomNav(bottomNav: BottomNavigationView) {
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        bottomNav.setupWithNavController(navHostFragment.navController)
        bottomNav.itemIconTintList = null

        vm.profileImgUrl.observe(this) { url ->
            bottomNav.menu.findItem(R.id.profileFragment).load(this, url) {
                transformations(CircleCropTransformation())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code draws the profile image on the BottomNavigationMenu.
But not draw the border.

When I googling, there is no support for CircleCrop with Border on Coil (even Glide).

So I tried the below code, But it doesn't work well..

```
vm.profileImg.observe(this) { imgBitmap ->
    val layerBorder = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.oval_trans_border1_red, null)
    val layerIcon = BitmapDrawable(Resources.getSystem(), imgBitmap)
    val layerDrawable = LayerDrawable(arrayOf(layerIcon, layerBorder))

    val bottomNavProfile = bottomNav.menu.findItem(R.id.profileFragment)
    val request = ImageRequest.Builder(this)
        .data(layerDrawable)
        .target {
            bottomNavProfile.icon = it
        }
        .apply {
            transformations(CircleCropTransformation())
        }
        .build()
    imageLoader.enqueue(request)
}
```

Somebody help me please?

Comment: When you load `profileImg` you can use a Transformation to add the border . It will give you a Drawable/Bitmap . have you tried this way ? If there is no transformation available you can create one . Its should not be hard you just have to modify `Circular Transformation` class when talking about Glide . something Like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53606048/4168607).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own Transformation with border like this:

```
class BorderedCircleCropTransformation(
    private val borderSize: Float = 0f,
    @ColorInt private val borderColor: Int = Color.BLUE
) : Transformation {

    override fun key(): String = BorderedCircleCropTransformation::class.java.name

    override suspend fun transform(pool: BitmapPool, input: Bitmap, size: Size): Bitmap {
        val borderOffset = (borderSize * 2).toInt()
        val halfWidth = input.width / 2
        val halfHeight = input.height / 2
        val circleRadius = Math.min(halfWidth, halfHeight).toFloat()
        val newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            input.width + borderOffset,
            input.height + borderOffset,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )

        // Center coordinates of the image
        val centerX = halfWidth + borderSize
        val centerY = halfHeight + borderSize

        val paint = Paint()
        val canvas = Canvas(newBitmap).apply {
            // Set transparent initial area
            drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
        }

        // Draw the transparent initial area
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, circleRadius, paint)

        // Draw the image
        paint.xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        canvas.drawBitmap(input, borderSize, borderSize, paint)

        // Draw the createBitmapWithBorder
        paint.xfermode = null
        paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        paint.color = borderColor
        paint.strokeWidth = borderSize
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, circleRadius, paint)
        return newBitmap
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?) = other is BorderedCircleCropTransformation

    override fun hashCode() = javaClass.hashCode()

    override fun toString() = "BorderedCircleCropTransformation()"

    private companion object {
        val XFERMODE = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    }
}

internal val Bitmap.safeConfig: Bitmap.Config
    get() = config ?: Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
```

then pass it as a transformation to coil and it will draw what you want.
I use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53606048/4168607) for drawing border.