# Glide circular image gets cropped

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide, rounded-corners

I'm trying to make a circular imageview using glide... 
I followed this tutorial [How to round an image with Glide library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278821/how-to-round-an-image-with-glide-library) but my image always get the top and bottom cropped

[image]

i tried to change imageview dimensions but nothing changes, always cropped and same ratio

what am i doing wrong

```
Glide.with(this).load(MasterFacade.getFacade().getLocalUser().getProfilePicUrl()).apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform()).into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImageView));
```

and the layout

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profileImageView"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profileImageView"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

The problem is that is overlaping the other views, with a margin it should solve your problem

Comment: it worked perfectly, but can you explain what is that margin doing? why do i need it? and HOW DID YOU GET 15 DP?

Comment: the margin is simply adding space of 15dp around all the image, its just like making space with the other views , it has margin top, marginright, marginleft and marginbottom

Comment: a better approach should be place that image above your post following and followers view and below your toolbar, if you have this inside a relativelayout you can do it with above and below

Comment: This solution hardly can help.

Answer (score 1):

```java
Glide.with(context)
    .load("https://yourImageUrl.jpg")
    .apply(new RequestOptions().circleCrop())
    .into(headerImage);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Yeah Sure @Mark_Rotteveel, Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

**Add xml layout:**

```
         <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:id="@+id/lay_profpic"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/border_circle">

                    <ImageView
                         android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
                         android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                         android:src="@color/white"
                         android:layout_gravity="center"
                         android:layout_width="90"
                         android:layout_height="90dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
```

**Add Java code use Glide**

```
Glide.with(this)
                .load(user.getProfilePicture())
                .transform(new CircleTransform(this))
                .into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(ivProfilePicture) {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable drawable, GlideAnimation anim) {
                        super.onResourceReady(drawable, anim);
                        ivProfilePicture.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                        ivProfilePicture.invalidate();
                        ivProfilePicture.requestLayout();
                    }
                });
```