# App Crashes when using CircularImage view from Url using Glide in Drawer Layout

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I'm using `Glide` and `CircularImageview` from [Github library](https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView)  to fetch image URL and show it into the `Drawerlayout`'s `ImageView`. It works fine and image is loaded. When I open the app and close the app without opening `NavigationDrawer`, it does not produced any error but when I open the app and open `DrawerLayout`, then press the back button to close the app, it crashes with the following error:

```
 Process: com.mscphysics.plusacademy, PID: 21955
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.mscphysics.plusacademy/com.mscphysics.plusacademy.PaidUser.Activity.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3498)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3516)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1249)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5018)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:589)
        at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.refreshBitmapShader(CircularImageView.java:341)
        at com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView.invalidate(CircularImageView.java:262)
        at android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(ImageView.java:426)
        at com.bumptech.glide.request.target.DrawableImageViewTarget.setResource(DrawableImageViewTarget.java:28)
        at com.bumptech.glide.request.target.DrawableImageViewTarget.setResource(DrawableImageViewTarget.java:10)
        at com.bumptech.glide.request.target.ImageViewTarget.setResourceInternal(ImageViewTarget.java:127)
        at com.bumptech.glide.request.target.ImageViewTarget.onLoadCleared(ImageViewTarget.java:97)
        at com.bumptech.glide.request.SingleRequest.clear(SingleRequest.java:319)
        at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestTracker.clearRemoveAndMaybeRecycle(RequestTracker.java:79)
        at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestTracker.clearRemoveAndRecycle(RequestTracker.java:66)
        at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.untrack(RequestManager.java:603)
        at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.untrackOrDelegate(RequestManager.java:571)
        at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.clear(RequestManager.java:559)
        at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.onDestroy(RequestManager.java:303)
        at com.bumptech.glide.manager.ActivityFragmentLifecycle.onDestroy(ActivityFragmentLifecycle.java:65)
        at com.bumptech.glide.manager.SupportRequestManagerFragment.onDestroy(SupportRequestManagerFragment.java:194)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performDestroy(Fragment.java:2588)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1566)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3244)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:3235)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchDestroy(FragmentController.java:265)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:390)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy(AppCompatActivity.java:209)
        at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5410)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3485)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3516) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1249) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5018) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My navigation drawer method is

```
public void updateNavHeader() {
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView navUsername = headerView.findViewById(R.id.nav_username);
    TextView navUserMail = headerView.findViewById(R.id.nav_user_mail);
    ImageView navUserPhot = headerView.findViewById(R.id.nav_user_photo);

    navUserMail.setText(currentUser.getEmail());
    navUsername.setText(currentUser.getDisplayName());

    // now we will use Glide to load user image
    // first we need to import the library
    Glide.with(this).load(currentUser.getPhotoUrl()).into(navUserPhot);
}
```

and my xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/nav_user_photo"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        app:border="true"
        app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
        app:border_width="4dp"
        app:shadow="true" />


    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@+id/nav_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="@string/nav_header_title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@+id/nav_user_mail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nav_header_subtitle" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Could anyone explain why it is throwing an error on opening the app and after opening navigation drawer and closing the app but not when only opening the app and simply closing it without opening the drawer.

Comment: You can use `RequestOptions().fitCenter().circleCrop()` as RequestOption to display a circled image using Glide instead :).

Comment: It looks like problem inside the library. Use diffrent one as mentioned or You can do it with Glide [How to round image with Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278821/how-to-round-an-image-with-glide-library)

Comment: You don't need to use any `CircularImageView library` as Glide provide `Rounded ImageView` feature: See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32390715/7254873

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a class for making an image circular, I don't know the source where to get this, but it is working fine with Glide

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import androidx.annotation.ColorInt;
import androidx.annotation.ColorRes;
import androidx.annotation.DrawableRes;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView;


public class CircleImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

    private static final ScaleType SCALE_TYPE = ScaleType.CENTER_CROP;

    private static final Bitmap.Config BITMAP_CONFIG = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    private static final int COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION = 2;

    private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH = 0;
    private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
    private static final int DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR = Color.TRANSPARENT;
    private static final boolean DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY = false;

    private final RectF mDrawableRect = new RectF();
    private final RectF mBorderRect = new RectF();

    private final Matrix mShaderMatrix = new Matrix();
    private final Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint mBorderPaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint mFillPaint = new Paint();

    private int mBorderColor = DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR;
    private int mBorderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;
    private int mFillColor = DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR;

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
    private int mBitmapWidth;
    private int mBitmapHeight;

    private float mDrawableRadius;
    private float mBorderRadius;

    private ColorFilter mColorFilter;

    private boolean mReady;
    private boolean mSetupPending;
    private boolean mBorderOverlay;
    private boolean mDisableCircularTransformation;

    public CircleImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init();
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircleImageView, defStyle, 0);

        mBorderWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_width, DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH);
        mBorderColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_color, DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
        mBorderOverlay = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_overlay, DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY);
        mFillColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_fill_color, DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR);

        a.recycle();

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        super.setScaleType(SCALE_TYPE);
        mReady = true;

        if (mSetupPending) {
            setup();
            mSetupPending = false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public ScaleType getScaleType() {
        return SCALE_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
        if (scaleType != SCALE_TYPE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("ScaleType %s not supported.", scaleType));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdjustViewBounds(boolean adjustViewBounds) {
        if (adjustViewBounds) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("adjustViewBounds not supported.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mDisableCircularTransformation) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            return;
        }

        if (mBitmap == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mFillColor != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
            canvas.drawCircle(mDrawableRect.centerX(), mDrawableRect.centerY(), mDrawableRadius, mFillPaint);
        }
        canvas.drawCircle(mDrawableRect.centerX(), mDrawableRect.centerY(), mDrawableRadius, mBitmapPaint);
        if (mBorderWidth > 0) {
            canvas.drawCircle(mBorderRect.centerX(), mBorderRect.centerY(), mBorderRadius, mBorderPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
        setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setPaddingRelative(int start, int top, int end, int bottom) {
        super.setPaddingRelative(start, top, end, bottom);
        setup();
    }

    public int getBorderColor() {
        return mBorderColor;
    }

    public void setBorderColor(@ColorInt int borderColor) {
        if (borderColor == mBorderColor) {
            return;
        }

        mBorderColor = borderColor;
        mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated Use {@link #setBorderColor(int)} instead
     */
    @Deprecated
    public void setBorderColorResource(@ColorRes int borderColorRes) {
        setBorderColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(borderColorRes));
    }

    /**
     * Return the color drawn behind the circle-shaped drawable.
     *
     * @return The color drawn behind the drawable
     * @deprecated Fill color support is going to be removed in the future
     */
    @Deprecated
    public int getFillColor() {
        return mFillColor;
    }

    /**
     * Set a color to be drawn behind the circle-shaped drawable. Note that
     * this has no effect if the drawable is opaque or no drawable is set.
     *
     * @param fillColor The color to be drawn behind the drawable
     * @deprecated Fill color support is going to be removed in the future
     */
    @Deprecated
    public void setFillColor(@ColorInt int fillColor) {
        if (fillColor == mFillColor) {
            return;
        }

        mFillColor = fillColor;
        mFillPaint.setColor(fillColor);
        invalidate();
    }


    public int getBorderWidth() {
        return mBorderWidth;
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth) {
        if (borderWidth == mBorderWidth) {
            return;
        }

        mBorderWidth = borderWidth;
        setup();
    }

    public boolean isBorderOverlay() {
        return mBorderOverlay;
    }

    public void setBorderOverlay(boolean borderOverlay) {
        if (borderOverlay == mBorderOverlay) {
            return;
        }

        mBorderOverlay = borderOverlay;
        setup();
    }

    public boolean isDisableCircularTransformation() {
        return mDisableCircularTransformation;
    }

    public void setDisableCircularTransformation(boolean disableCircularTransformation) {
        if (mDisableCircularTransformation == disableCircularTransformation) {
            return;
        }

        mDisableCircularTransformation = disableCircularTransformation;
        initializeBitmap();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
        initializeBitmap();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        initializeBitmap();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageResource(@DrawableRes int resId) {
        super.setImageResource(resId);
        initializeBitmap();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageURI(Uri uri) {
        super.setImageURI(uri);
        initializeBitmap();
    }

    @Override
    public ColorFilter getColorFilter() {
        return mColorFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        if (cf == mColorFilter) {
            return;
        }

        mColorFilter = cf;
        applyColorFilter();
        invalidate();
    }

    private void applyColorFilter() {
        if (mBitmapPaint != null) {
            mBitmapPaint.setColorFilter(mColorFilter);
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        }

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap;

            if (drawable instanceof ColorDrawable) {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, BITMAP_CONFIG);
            } else {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), BITMAP_CONFIG);
            }

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            drawable.draw(canvas);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void initializeBitmap() {
        if (mDisableCircularTransformation) {
            mBitmap = null;
        } else {
            mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable());
        }
        setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        if (!mReady) {
            mSetupPending = true;
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 && getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (mBitmap == null) {
            invalidate();
            return;
        }

        mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(mBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        mBitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBitmapPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

        mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mBorderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
        mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);

        mFillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mFillPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mFillPaint.setColor(mFillColor);

        mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
        mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();

        mBorderRect.set(calculateBounds());
        mBorderRadius = Math.min((mBorderRect.height() - mBorderWidth) / 2.0f, (mBorderRect.width() - mBorderWidth) / 2.0f);

        mDrawableRect.set(mBorderRect);
        if (!mBorderOverlay && mBorderWidth > 0) {
            mDrawableRect.inset(mBorderWidth - 1.0f, mBorderWidth - 1.0f);
        }
        mDrawableRadius = Math.min(mDrawableRect.height() / 2.0f, mDrawableRect.width() / 2.0f);

        applyColorFilter();
        updateShaderMatrix();
        invalidate();
    }

    private RectF calculateBounds() {
        int availableWidth = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
        int availableHeight = getHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();

        int sideLength = Math.min(availableWidth, availableHeight);

        float left = getPaddingLeft() + (availableWidth - sideLength) / 2f;
        float top = getPaddingTop() + (availableHeight - sideLength) / 2f;

        return new RectF(left, top, left + sideLength, top + sideLength);
    }

    private void updateShaderMatrix() {
        float scale;
        float dx = 0;
        float dy = 0;

        mShaderMatrix.set(null);

        if (mBitmapWidth * mDrawableRect.height() > mDrawableRect.width() * mBitmapHeight) {
            scale = mDrawableRect.height() / (float) mBitmapHeight;
            dx = (mDrawableRect.width() - mBitmapWidth * scale) * 0.5f;
        } else {
            scale = mDrawableRect.width() / (float) mBitmapWidth;
            dy = (mDrawableRect.height() - mBitmapHeight * scale) * 0.5f;
        }

        mShaderMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        mShaderMatrix.postTranslate((int) (dx + 0.5f) + mDrawableRect.left, (int) (dy + 0.5f) + mDrawableRect.top);

        mBitmapShader.setLocalMatrix(mShaderMatrix);
    }

}
```

Also, these are the attributes for XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CircleImageView">
        <attr name="civ_border_width" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="civ_border_color" format="color" />
        <attr name="civ_border_overlay" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="civ_fill_color" format="color" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Use it in your layout file

```
<YOUR_PACKAGE.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageUser"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
         />
```

Answer (score 1):

please use this [CircleImageView library](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) instead.
this is a library that i have seen used in many projects for Circular images
this should solve your problem

this is an example

```xml
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```