# Make ImageView fit width of CardView

Tags: android, imageview, android-appcompat, android-cardview

I have a `CardView` with rounded corners, I want to have an `ImageView` at the top like shown in the example taken from the material design guidelines below.

[image: components_cards8.png]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/card_view"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

     <!-- ... --> 
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Then inside the `CardView` I have this `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/default_cover" />
```

If I have the `card_view:cardCornerRadius` set to `0dp` then the `ImageView` fits the card like how I want it to.

[image: image_1]

However, the [material design guidelines](http://www.google.co.uk/design/spec/components/cards.html#cards-usage) state that cards should have rounded corners, and not square corners.

The problem I have is when I set the `card_view:cardCornerRadius` to something other than  `0dp`, e.g. `4dp`, then the following happens:

[image: image_2]

As can be seen, the `ImageView` does not fit into the `CardView`.

My question is, how can I make this `ImageView` fit to the layout of the `CardView` when it has rounded corners.

Comment: Daniel it could be happening on API below 21(5.0) Lollipop  , the same issue exist in play store app as well

Comment: @Vipinhelloindia Yeah you are right, this only happens pre-L. The class overview for CardView (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) describes what happens pre-L because corner clipping seems to be a feature of L and above only.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You need to do 2 things :

1) Call `setPreventCornerOverlap(false)` on your CardView.

2) Put ***rounded*** Imageview inside CardView

About rounding your imageview, I had the same problem so I made a library that you can set ***different radii on each corners***. There is one good library(vinc3m1’s RoundedImageView) that supports rounded corners on ImageView, but it only supports the same radii on every corners. But I wanted it to be rounded ***only*** top left and top right corners.

Finally I got the result what I wanted like below.

https://github.com/pungrue26/SelectableRoundedImageView

[image: Rounded ImageView inside CardView]

Comment: On newer versions, vinc3m1’s RoundedImageView support rounding specific corners.

Comment: really bad, what If I don't want ImageView to be rounded and it has FitCenter instead of CenterCrop or FitXY?

Answer (score 28):

If your image size (width) is fixed with your `ImageView` width, you just only have to do is change your `ImageView` attribute to :

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

That is. No additional image corner rounding, no busy work. Beside it efficient for app's performance.

Note : my suggestion may not appropriate for small image with large size `ImageView`.

Comment: I don't understand all the upvotes for this. An ImageView directly under a CardView, or in any ViewGroup below it, will overwrite the rounded corners instead of fitting the image into the inside of the rounded corners.

Comment: very bad, corners are gone, ImageView is square!

Answer (score 15):

[image: CardView with ImageView]

I got this to work by putting a `RoundedImageView` inside of a `CardView`.  Also you need to set the appropriate `CardView` attributes.

https://medium.com/@etiennelawlor/layout-tips-for-pre-and-post-lollipop-bcb2e4cdd6b2#.kmb24wtkk

Comment: Please add relevant information to answer instead of relying on the link. `RoundedImageView` is not an official class.

Comment: My heart pumped fast when he said RoundedImageView I thought it was official

Answer (score 7):

EDIT 2015/09/29

https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView added support of rounding of  selected corners

You can also use makeramen RoundedImageView https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView,
and to remove auto padding in CardView for pre LolliPop use

yourCardView.setPreventCornerOverlap(false);

And then set padding you needded to show shadows of cardview

Comment: vinc3m1’s RoundedImageView is a good library, but it only supports the same radiuses on every corners. But ImageView inside CardView should be rounded only top left and top right corners. So I made one that you can set different radiuses on each corners. https://github.com/pungrue26/SelectableRoundedImageView

Comment: You're right. I will try your lib some day. Last time i faced similiar problem i hided bottom corners by another view, text view for example. Dirty workaround though.

Answer (score 4):

Make a `bck_rounded.xml` in `drawable` folder. Give it a radius that is same as the card_view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape>
```

Apply inside your imageView: `android:background="@drawable/bck_rounded"`

Comment: the image view should also have rounded corners... try this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20743859/3879470 with stroke and padding.

Answer (score 2):

just add this line in to your `CardView`

```
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
```

and set `ImageScale` on your `ImageView`

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with setting
1) `app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"`
2) setting a rounded `imageView` background

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to Customize Your ImageView.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class RoundedImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {
private Paint mPaint;
private Path mPath;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Matrix mMatrix;
private int mRadius = convertDpToPixel(10);
private int mWidth;
private int mHeight;
private Drawable mDrawable;

 public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    mPath = new Path();
}

public int convertDpToPixel(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, displayMetrics);
}

@Override
public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    mDrawable = drawable;
    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }
    mBitmap = drawableToBitmap(drawable);
    int bDIWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
    int bDIHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
    //Fit to screen.
    float scale;
    if ((mHeight / (float) bDIHeight) >= (mWidth / (float) bDIWidth)) {
        scale = mHeight / (float) bDIHeight;
    } else {
        scale = mWidth / (float) bDIWidth;
    }
    float borderLeft = (mWidth - (bDIWidth * scale)) / 2;
    float borderTop = (mHeight - (bDIHeight * scale)) / 2;
    mMatrix = getImageMatrix();
    RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, bDIWidth, bDIHeight);
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(borderLeft, borderTop, (bDIWidth * scale) + borderLeft, (bDIHeight * scale) + borderTop);
    mMatrix.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    invalidate();
}

private Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        if (bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        }
    }
    if (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
    } else {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    mWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    mHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    if ((mDrawable != null) && (mHeight > 0) && (mWidth > 0)) {
        setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (mBitmap == null) {
        return;
    }
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(0, mRadius);
    mPath.lineTo(0, canvas.getHeight());
    mPath.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    mPath.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(), mRadius);
    mPath.quadTo(canvas.getWidth(), 0, canvas.getWidth() - mRadius, 0);
    mPath.lineTo(mRadius, 0);
    mPath.quadTo(0, 0, 0, mRadius);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    canvas.clipPath(mPath);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mMatrix, mPaint);
}
}
```

And in layout.xml

```
<com.example.widget.RoundedImageViewmageView
            android:id="@+id/ivProductImg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes using `Glide` instead of `Picasso` for loading images also helps.

Answer (score 0):

i try to using combination with cardview and imageview, so it will be like this :

```
    android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/kmp_warna1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I just adding the corner radius and elevation attribute on cardview, and scaletype = centerCrop on image view

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the MaskedCardView and worked for me

```
    class MaskedCardView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = R.attr.materialCardViewStyle
) : MaterialCardView(context, attrs, defStyle) {
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    private val pathProvider = ShapeAppearancePathProvider()
    private val path: Path = Path()
    private val shapeAppearance: ShapeAppearanceModel = ShapeAppearanceModel.builder(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyle,
        R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_CardView
    ).build()

    private val rectF = RectF(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        canvas.clipPath(path)
        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        rectF.right = w.toFloat()
        rectF.bottom = h.toFloat()
        pathProvider.calculatePath(shapeAppearance, 1f, rectF, path)
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
    }
}
```

And use with it the attribute app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"

Answer (score 0):

An updated solution that worked for me:

Go to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file and find the parent `activity` that is mentioned in the `manifest` file. Simply add the following line inside the activity tag.
`android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`
Just run the application again and see it has been resolved the corner radius issue.

Example:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".mvvm.activities.ABCDActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">

            <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/app_navigation"/>

        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these codes to fit an image into circle cardview:

**XML:**

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="35dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="center"></ImageView>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**NOTE:** cardCornerRadius attribute usually equal 1/2 width and height of CardView

**USE PICASSO TO LOAD ONLINE IMAGE:**

```
    ImageView imv = findViewById(R.id.imageView_id);
    Picasso.get().load("link image").resize(300, 300).centerCrop().into(imv);
```