# Create gridview in one line

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap

I need to create a gridview and set image from asset this gridview will be in one line and one column. After that I select one photo and transfer it to another activity.

This is code of my second activity

```
package com.testcamera.hassanechafai.testcamera;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class CallActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_call);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView);



    }
```

This is code of the first activity (where I want to set gridview)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


public class FirstActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String selectedImagePath = "";
    final private int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 2;
    ImageView imgView;
    private String imgPath;
    Intent myIntent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
        Button butCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        butCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final Intent intent = new Intent(
                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        setImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        Button butGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button2);
        butGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, ""),
                        PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        final EditText save = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        Button myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Save);


        myBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int time = Integer.parseInt(save.getText().toString());
                if (time > 0) {

                     myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);
                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, time);
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Starting Activity in: " + time + " seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

This is code of alarm receiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm time reached", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.testcamera.hassanechafai.testcamera", "com.testcamera.hassanechafai.testcamera.CallActivity");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

I need to choose one picture from gridview and transfer it by passing in alarmreceiver

Comment: Add your code what you have tried and explain your question more in detail

Comment: Could you show your code? Have you already tried anything?

Comment: CHECK THIS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394300/make-imageview-fit-width-of-cardview

Comment: @Alexey Gorozhanov  no but i will add code of my activities

Comment: @VicJordan look at my last edit

Comment: @Alexey Gorozhanov look at my last edit