# Rounded Gradient Shadow

Tags: android

Can you help me with a solution for custom color shadow with gradient effect?

I need this effect for ImageView shadow

[image]

For example, I try to use gradient like:

```
              <gradient
                android:type="radial"
                android:startColor="#000000"
                android:endColor="#43bababa"
                android:gradientRadius="100dp"
                android:angle="270"/>
```

[image]

But this gradient has ring effect, not rounded corners.

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution. I am stuck in a similar situation.

Answer (score -1):

There's problem in every possible solution:

About shadows:

1. You can use CardView. It has rounded corners and shadows out of the box. But as I know compat realization doesn't cut corners of inner layouts. It just fits image in it (as result tiny white strokes around image [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394300/make-imageview-fit-width-of-cardview))
2. You can use 9 patch image as background. Not so easy to place layout layers correctly

**SOLUTION YOU WILL LIKE:**
Use CardView with [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView/)

Comment: `It has rounded corners and shadows out of the box.` shadows don't always work for me for some reason even with CardView :o

Comment: you cannot customize shadows like that with CardView