# Imageview not taking corner radius of cardview

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

Hi i'm developing an app where i'm using imageview inside cardview but my problem is that imageview somehow is not taking the corner radius applied to cardview
Please see the image below
[image]
I tried doing different things but dont understand where the problem is please if anyone can guide me
my xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardview2"
    app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="88dp"
            android:layout_height="88dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:scaleX="1.2"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:scaleY="1.2"
            android:src="@drawable/club1"
            android:background="@drawable/corner_radius"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="Item"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/ratingTextView"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:drawableEnd="@color/White"
            android:drawableRight="@color/White"
            android:drawablePadding="2dp"
            android:text="4,5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>



    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: did you tried to set image as background of CardView

Comment: yes @Meline i tried setting it as background of cardview as well

Comment: Use custom background or use margins. Setting padding to the parent view may helps

Comment: what do you mean by custom background @Jyoti JK

Comment: Use `app:contentPadding="10dp"` for card view. And let `ViewGroup's` as `wrap_content`.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394300/make-imageview-fit-width-of-cardview

Comment: remove    `android:scaleX="1.2"` and  `android:scaleY="1.2"`  from your imageview

Comment: use scaleType as centerCrop

Comment: @Smith use drawable with stroke , corner as what you want . And apply it to imageview.

Comment: @RajasekaranM i tried center crop as well but corner radius is not getting applied to image

Comment: use `match_parent` for width instead of `88dp` at image view

Comment: because your image view width 12 dp lesser than your parent layout ,that's why radius not applied :-)

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: remove margin in linear layout too

Answer (score 3):

See here is the Image. Remeber Don't make `CardView` as Main Layout.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_suvichar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_suvichar_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Title"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text_size" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you response but i ende up using custom imageview as @Nilesh suggested

Answer (score 2):

Try Replace your Linear Layout with Relative Layout.
After that set gravity of your last textview (center_horizontal).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `RoundedImageView` :

Put this in the build.gradle

`compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'`

And to use it:

```
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:riv_corner_radius="5dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just use this code in xml and see result after RUN the code:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/recipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="ITEM"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="34"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: hi Deven can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939514/trying-to-implement-viewpager-with-cardstack-swipe-animation

Answer (score -1):

[image: please find]   **Try this way :**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
  android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
  cardview:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_3sdp"
  cardview:cardElevation="@dimen/_3sdp"
  cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_180sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"/>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:id="@+id/rlMiddle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPrescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:text="Demo"
            android:textStyle="bold"
           />
      </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Hi @jeet parmar tried your answer but still not getting corner radius for imageview

Comment: can you please send your new xml ?

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_35sdp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/walletList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

Comment: can you please RecyclerView layout if any problem in that ?.

Comment: Hi @jeet parmar can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939514/trying-to-implement-viewpager-with-cardstack-swipe-animation

Comment: it is gradle file  

implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'

Comment: jeet parmar can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939514/trying-to-implement-viewpager-with-cardstack-swipe-animation

Comment: jeet parmar can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939514/trying-to-implement-viewpager-with-cardstack-swipe-animation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170071/discussion-between-jeet-parmar-and-smith).