# make an ImageView with rounded corners?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface, rounding

[image]
**rounded corners of cardview**
I want to make the interface as shown above. The images are not fixed, which means I can transfer images to other. I want to use pakage in xml file. Something like,

```
<com.example.widgets.RoundedImageView
    android: layout_width = "39dp"
    android: layout_height = "39dp"
    android: src = "@ drawable / your_drawable" />
```

Comment: use android `CardView`

Comment: yes agree with @Sanoop you can use card-view to create this layout

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Round Corner image in ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31675420/set-round-corner-image-in-imageview)

Answer (score 0):

your drawable code should like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle">
        <!-- <solid android:color="add your color here"/>-->
        <solid android:color="#00000"/> 
        <stroke
            android:color="add your color here"
            android:width="1dp"/>
        <corners
            android:radius="5dp"/>


    </shape>
```

**in XML**

```
  <com.example.widgets.RoundedImageView
                android: layout_width = "39dp"
                android: layout_height = "39dp"
                android:background="here is your background source"
                android: src = "@ drawable / your_drawable"
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this component . 
 https://github.com/pungrue26/SelectableRoundedImageView

```
       <com.utility.SelectableRoundedImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:sriv_left_top_corner_radius="55dp"
            app:sriv_right_top_corner_radius="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
           />
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to use any third party libraries then you can Customize Your ImageView.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class RoundedImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {
private Paint mPaint;
private Path mPath;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Matrix mMatrix;
private int mRadius = convertDpToPixel(10);
private int mWidth;
private int mHeight;
private Drawable mDrawable;

 public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    mPath = new Path();
}

public int convertDpToPixel(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, displayMetrics);
}

@Override
public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    mDrawable = drawable;
    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }
    mBitmap = drawableToBitmap(drawable);
    int bDIWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
    int bDIHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
    //Fit to screen.
    float scale;
    if ((mHeight / (float) bDIHeight) >= (mWidth / (float) bDIWidth)) {
        scale = mHeight / (float) bDIHeight;
    } else {
        scale = mWidth / (float) bDIWidth;
    }
    float borderLeft = (mWidth - (bDIWidth * scale)) / 2;
    float borderTop = (mHeight - (bDIHeight * scale)) / 2;
    mMatrix = getImageMatrix();
    RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, bDIWidth, bDIHeight);
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(borderLeft, borderTop, (bDIWidth * scale) + borderLeft, (bDIHeight * scale) + borderTop);
    mMatrix.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    invalidate();
}

private Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        if (bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        }
    }
    if (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
    } else {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    mWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    mHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    if ((mDrawable != null) && (mHeight > 0) && (mWidth > 0)) {
        setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (mBitmap == null) {
        return;
    }
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(0, mRadius);
    mPath.lineTo(0, canvas.getHeight());
    mPath.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    mPath.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(), mRadius);
    mPath.quadTo(canvas.getWidth(), 0, canvas.getWidth() - mRadius, 0);
    mPath.lineTo(mRadius, 0);
    mPath.quadTo(0, 0, 0, mRadius);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    canvas.clipPath(mPath);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mMatrix, mPaint);
}
}
```

And in layout.xml

```
<com.example.widget.RoundedImageViewmageView
            android:id="@+id/ivProductImg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />
```

Comment: it works but it sets the radius for the top left and right corners!