# Circular Imageview in android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I want circular ImageView in my app. I found some code but this is only round the corner image not to circle. Here is my code. Also check the image.

[image]

```
   public class CircularImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

public CircularImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

    Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundBitmap(bitmap, w);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

}

public static Bitmap getRoundBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sBmp;

    if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
        float smallest = Math.min(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
        float factor = smallest / radius;
        sBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int)(bmp.getWidth() / factor), (int)(bmp.getHeight() / factor), false);
    } else {
        sBmp = bmp;
    }

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xffa19774;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, radius, radius);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    canvas.drawCircle(radius / 2 + 0.7f,
            radius / 2 + 0.7f, radius / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sBmp, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}

 }
```

And Here is xml file

```
 <com.example.CircularImageView
          android:layout_width="70dp"
          android:layout_height="70dp"
          app:srcCompt="@drawable/dummy />
```

I read many answers on stackoverflow but nothing found according to my requirements. I don't want to use any library I want to create my own code.
I'm new in android can you please let me know want I'm missing in my code.

Comment: "I found some code but this is only round image not to circle" -- please explain the difference. You might consider uploading an image somewhere and linking to it from your "question". "nothing found according to my requirements" -- please explain, **in detail**, what your "requirements" are.

Comment: @CommonsWare please check I update my question. Round means it only round corners

Comment: Well, when I search `android imageview rounded corners` on Google, I find a variety of solutions. Clearly, you must have made a similar search. When you tried [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20743859/115145) and [this blog post](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/11/how-to-make-imageview-image-rounded-corner-in-android.html) and so forth, what problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try to extend `CircularImageView` from `ImageView` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView`.

**CircularImageView.java**

```
package com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CircularImageView extends ImageView {

    public CircularImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

        Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundBitmap(bitmap, w);
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    }

    public static Bitmap getRoundBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
        Bitmap sBmp;

        if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
            float smallest = Math.min(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
            float factor = smallest / radius;
            sBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int)(bmp.getWidth() / factor), (int)(bmp.getHeight() / factor), false);
        } else {
            sBmp = bmp;
        }

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final String color = "#BAB399";
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, radius, radius);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
        canvas.drawCircle(radius / 2 + 0.7f, radius / 2 + 0.7f, radius / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(sBmp, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }

}
```

2. In your XML, try using attribute `android:src` instead of `app:srcCompt`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:gravity="center">

       <com.ferdous.stackoverflowanswer.CircularImageView
           android:layout_width="200dp"
           android:layout_height="200dp"
           android:src="@drawable/dummy"
           android:background="#ff0000"/>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```

**OUTPUT:**

[image: enter code here]

Hope this will help~

Comment: @FiverrProjects I have updated my answer. See the attached image for output of my code. Hope it will help

Comment: @FiverrProjects If my answer seems useful then please give an up vote. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to create `RoundedImageView` using `ImageView` and `CardView`

Check this example: https://github.com/SergeySharipov/RoundedImageView

Add the following dependency to your app module's **build.gradle** file:

```
 dependencies {
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
 }
```

Add the code to your layout and change "YOUR_PICTURE":

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_for_image"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="100dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rounded_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/YOUR_PICTURE" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can use `fresco lib` for circular [image](http://frescolib.org/docs/using-drawees-xml.html).
- You will need just add attribute `fresco:roundAsCircle="true"` in the `xml layout` as per the documentation.
- Also this library is useful for `asynchronous` image loading from the web.

Comment: I do not want to use any Lib

Answer (score 0):

Use Piccasso is a library really popular

In your gradle

```
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

In your code:

```
Transformation transformation = new RoundedTransformationBuilder()
            .cornerRadiusDp(40)
            .oval(false)
            .build();

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(//Your url image or bitmap)
            .fit()
            .transform(transformation)
            .into(//Your imageview);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use material libraries shapeable image view.

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearance.App.Image.Circle"
    />
```

Put this code below to styles.xml

```
<style name="ShapeAppearance.App.Image.Circle" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

For kotlin developers I suggest [coil library](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil) it has various animations and crop functions :

```
imageView.load("https://www.example.com/image.jpg") {
   crossfade(true)
   placeholder(R.drawable.image)
   transformations(CircleCropTransformation())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//add dependencies

implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

//Image Link
https://unsplash.com/photos/2LowviVHZ-E

//xml code

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/circleview1"
    android:layout_width="92dp"
    android:layout_height="92dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60.0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/unslpash"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```