# CardView on Android 5.1 - why show rhombus instead of a circle?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, cardview

I have an CardView with ImageView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/message_avatar_card"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
        android:innerRadius="0dp"
        android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
        android:background="@color/fui_transparent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/message_avatar"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@color/fui_transparent"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

On Android 9.0 all is ok, see screenshot

### [image: android 9]

But on Android 5.1 I see rhombus , not circle

### [image: android 5.1]

**How to fix it?**

Comment: why don't you using **[`CircleImageView`](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView#circleimageview)**

Comment: I want do it without third-implementation

Comment: check this than https://stackoverflow.com/a/43378661/7666442

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/message_avatar_card"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:innerRadius="0dp"
        android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
        android:background="@color/fui_transparent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/message_avatar"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@color/fui_transparent"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`CircleImageView`** library :

```
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
```

in XML :

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/message_avatar"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:civ_border_color="YOUR_COLOR"/> // if you don't want give any border remove this line
```

In java :

```
CircleImageView message_avatar = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.message_avatar);
```

if you are set image dynamically use **`Picasso`** library:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

in Java

```
Picasso.with(context).load(IMAGE_PATH).into(message_avatar);
```