# How should i create an circle image view in Android studio using JAVA

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am making an app like Instagram in Android Studio using JAVA framework and Firebase for the backend.
I want to know how i can make circle image view in it that can be used for profile picture.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Circular Imageview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43378223/circular-imageview-in-android)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do believe you are looking for following result -

[image]

You should use a very popular library [CircularImageView](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView)

Add library to your build.gradle(Module App)

```
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:4.2.0'
```

You can create image view just like you create ImageView in your xml.

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    app:civ_border_color="#3f51b5"
    app:civ_border_width="4dp"
    app:civ_shadow="true"
    app:civ_shadow_radius="10"
    app:civ_shadow_color="#3f51b5"/>
```

In you code you can referance same view as -

```
CircularImageView circularImageView = findViewById(R.id.circularImageView);
```

Please check the [documentation](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView#xml) for more customization.

Happy Coding !

Comment: Thank a lot for this amazing suggestion.

Comment: It helped me to make a basic interface

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information