# Image Corner Radius

Tags: android, xml

Is there any way to round the corners of an `ImageView` through `xml layout`? And even if not, what are the ways we can achieve that?

PS: The `image urls` are being fetched from an API. Not from `drawable` folder

Comment: try sample from this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743859/imageview-rounded-corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743859/imageview-rounded-corners)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImageView rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743859/imageview-rounded-corners)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using **[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)** library

use

```
Glide
  .with(context)
  .load(url)
  .apply(
      RequestOptions()
        .circleCrop())
  .into(imageView)
```

Comment: so you are using api, use glide

Comment: I am using Picasso. Can it be done with that? Or else I'll use Glide. And anyways, this has been in my head for a while now, should I be using Picasso or Glide

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using custom views like this

```
public class RoundImageView extends ImageView {

    private float mRadius = 18.0f;
    private Path mPath;
    private RectF mRect;

    public RoundImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public RoundImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public RoundImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mPath = new Path();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mRect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

        mPath.addRoundRect(mRect, mRadius, mRadius, Path.Direction.CW);

        canvas.clipPath(mPath);

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

and use it in your XML

```
<your_pkag.RoundImageView
     android:id="@+id/imgView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

Comment: How is the java file RoundImageView being used in xml?

Comment: like this `<your_pkag.RoundImageView
     android:id="@+id/imgView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/image" />`

Comment: Also, I am getting images from my api, so `android:background="@drawable/image" ` will not work? Or can it? Because the image urls are coming from the API and I set it in the ImageView. So I don't think it will be possible to set it as a background.

Comment: remove `android:background="@drawable/image"` and use `android:src="@drawable/image"`. i updated my answer

Comment: Okay. Thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to make. But for the borders.

You can create a drawable file like below.

`line.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000" />
</shape>
```

`activity_xxx.xml`

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height:"200dp"
        android:layout_width:"200dp"
        android:background:"@drawable/line.xml"
    />
```