# How do I make a circular imageButton with accurate borders?

Tags: java, android, imageview

There are some libraries for circular imageViews but their hitbox expands far beyond the perimeter of the circle , I am looking for something that acts as a circular button with a background.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61086632/7666442

Comment: This is not good enough, the clicking range is still far beyond the borders of the circle