# Add a background image to Customshape in xml Android

Tags: android, xml, xamarin.android

I have to use this code image is show but radius is not apply.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_image">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
      <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
   </shape>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: @pskink rounded corner not apply like this [link](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2F1.bp.blogspot.com%2F-s1aUZokppoc%2FT1oo5gmmyKI%2FAAAAAAAABtA%2Fyf9aPYpIuzM%2Fs1600%2Fdevice-2012-03-09-235829.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.gunawan.me%2F&h=800&w=480&tbnid=6qiOy_cw1OJGsM%3A&zoom=1&docid=eLe59bJDgyPxIM&ei=xzjBU-afH9DHuATfgoCIAw&tbm=isch&client=firefox-a&ved=0CAgQMygAMAA4rAI&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=385&page=8&start=266&ndsp=38)

Answer (score 0):

As I see from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)
 you can't use `android:padding="10dp"` in shape item. Also please see this answers:
[Android ImageView with Rounded Corners not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539781/android-imageview-with-rounded-corners-not-working)
[How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners)
I am not sure will you be able to make a rounded rectangle in xml with custom image. I saw result with inheriting from ImageView.

Comment: thanks for reply.. Remove this **<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_image">** line above code working rounded corner. but i want to this type of view like [link](https://c3409409.ssl.cf0.rackcdn.com/xamarin.vanillaforums.com/FileUpload/22/b8ee5d9a058a41bf7dbd6a22f31f62.png).