# Rounded corner ImageView - Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, rounded-corners

I try to create imageview  with rounded corners.i searched and found xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<solid android:color="#00ffffff" />

<padding
    android:bottom="6dp"
    android:left="6dp"
    android:right="6dp"
    android:top="6dp" />

<corners android:radius="12dp" />

<stroke
    android:width="6dp"
    android:color="#ffffffff" />
```

and this is a my imageview xml code

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/slidemenuuserimage"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:background="@drawable/frame" />
```

i have one problem.when i added background image programmatically i receive divirent result.

```
slidemenuuserimage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.slidemenuuserimage);
    slidemenuuserimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myuserimg);
```

this is a my result
[image]

how i can add padding left or right programmatically.in my option this is a my problem
if anyone knows solution please help me

Comment: what is the problem now ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also do this programatically

```
public Bitmap roundCornerImage(Bitmap raw, float round) {
  int width = raw.getWidth();
  int height = raw.getHeight();
  Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
  canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

  final Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

  final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
  final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

  canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, round, round, paint);

  paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.raw_IN));
  canvas.drawBitmap(raw, rect, rect, paint);

  return result;
 }
```

Use it like

```
slidemenuuserimage.setImageBitmap(roundCornerImage(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourImage),50)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out this `shape`

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <solid android:color="#00ffffff"/>    

    <stroke android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#ffffffff"/>

    <padding android:left="1dp"
             android:top="1dp"
             android:right="1dp"
             android:bottom="1dp"/> 

    <corners android:radius="30px"/> 
</shape>
```

Code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6539978/4385913)

Comment: thanks but my problem is in java code (slidemenuuserimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myuserimg);)  how i can solve my problem ? @Joan Colmenero

Answer (score -2):

you need to set src image, not background. So use `setImageResource()`  not `setBackgroundResource()`