# How to fix Profile image like instagram in android

Tags: android, imageview

I am developing an application which is required fixed profile image like instagram.. is it possible? 
  if anyone have idea plz help...

Comment: You mean to say in rounded shape??

Comment: ya.. i want to display lmage in rounded shape..

Comment: same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112150/android-create-circular-image-with-picasso

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28297409/1061944. It is already answered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rounded corner ImageView - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297164/rounded-corner-imageview-android)

Comment: Here i am trying for fix the profile image.. it means that not loading everytime..

Answer (score 1):

```
//this is java class
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageViewRounded extends ImageView {

    public ImageViewRounded(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ImageViewRounded(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ImageViewRounded(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        Bitmap fullSizeBitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

        int scaledWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        int scaledHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

        Bitmap mScaledBitmap;
        if (scaledWidth == fullSizeBitmap.getWidth()
                && scaledHeight == fullSizeBitmap.getHeight()) {
            mScaledBitmap = fullSizeBitmap;
        } else {
            mScaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fullSizeBitmap,
                scaledWidth, scaledHeight, true /* filter */);
        }

        // Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundedCornerBitmap(mScaledBitmap);

        // Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundedCornerBitmap(getContext(),
        // mScaledBitmap, 10, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, false, false,
        // false, false);
        // canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

        Bitmap circleBitmap = getCircledBitmap(mScaledBitmap);

    canvas.drawBitmap(circleBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    }

    public Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Context context, Bitmap input,
        int pixels, int w, int h, boolean squareTL, boolean squareTR,
        boolean squareBL, boolean squareBR) {

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        final float densityMultiplier = context.getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics().density;

        final int color = 0xff424242;

        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, w, h);
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

        // make sure that our rounded corner is scaled appropriately
        final float roundPx = pixels * densityMultiplier;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        // draw rectangles over the corners we want to be square
        if (squareTL) {
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, w / 2, h / 2, paint);
        }
        if (squareTR) {
            canvas.drawRect(w / 2, 0, w, h / 2, paint);
        }
        if (squareBL) {
            canvas.drawRect(0, h / 2, w / 2, h, paint);
        }
        if (squareBR) {
            canvas.drawRect(w / 2, h / 2, w, h, paint);
        }

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(input, 0, 0, paint);

        return output;
    }

    Bitmap getCircledBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);

        int color = Color.BLUE;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        // canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
        canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
            bitmap.getHeight() / 2, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return result;
    }

}
```

//use in xml

```
<yourpackagename.ImageViewRounded
        android:id="@+id/ivProfile"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/face" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use this java file 

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class RoundImage extends ImageView {
    public RoundImage(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(ctx, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();
        Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundedCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public static Bitmap getRoundedCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius) {
        Bitmap finalBitmap;
        if (bitmap.getWidth() != radius || bitmap.getHeight() != radius)
            finalBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, radius, radius,
                    false);
        else
            finalBitmap = bitmap;
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                finalBitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                finalBitmap.getHeight());
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
        canvas.drawCircle(finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2 + 0.7f,
                finalBitmap.getHeight() / 2 + 0.7f,
                finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(finalBitmap, rect, rect, paint);
        return output;
    }
}
```

Now, in your xml layout change imageview like this:

```
               <com.packagename.RoundImage
                android:id="@+id/profile_icon"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/default_image_male" />
```

Now, in activity you have to use RoundImage instead of ImageView.

Comment: <com.pacakgename.RoundImage
                android:id="@+id/profile_icon"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/default_image_male" />

Comment: here ur answer is only for roundimage.. but here i want to fix the profile image. i.e not loading everytime..

Comment: from where you want to load image from gallery, camera capture or from server?

Comment: Download picasso library from here - http://square.github.io/picasso/ , and then import to your projects. After importing use this code to load url into imageview " Picasso.with(this)
    .load("url")
    .fit().into(imageview); "

Comment: actually i used this in fragment.. in the fragment very first time i want load image.. i dont want load every time when i call the fragment. i tried picasso also..  but image is loading repeatedly when i call the fragment repeatedly...

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by file cache.

//Make this java file

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.wholesaleraja.R;
import com.wholesaleraja.adapter.Utils;

public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;
    // Handler to display images in UI thread
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.raja;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {

        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // Download Images from the Internet
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
            stream1.close();

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            // Recommended Size 512
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                handler.post(bd);
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if (bitmap != null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

//Make another java file for cache

```
import java.io.File;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class FileCache {
    private File cacheDir;
    private static final String Main_DIRECTORY_NAME = "File";
    private static final String Cache_DIRECTORY_NAME = "_cache";

    public FileCache(Context context) {
        // Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir = new File(
                    android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Main_DIRECTORY_NAME),
                    Cache_DIRECTORY_NAME);
        else
            cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        // if (!cacheDir.exists())
        // cacheDir.mkdirs();

        if (!cacheDir.exists()) {
            if (!cacheDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(Cache_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + Cache_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");

            }
        }
    }

    public File getFile(String url) {
        String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        // String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;

    }

    public void clear() {
        File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
        if (files == null)
            return;
        for (File f : files)
            f.delete();
    }
}
```

//Make another java file for memory cache

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Log;

public class MemoryCache {
    private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";

    // Last argument true for LRU ordering
    private Map<String, Bitmap> cache = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10, 1.5f, true));

    // Current allocated size
    private long size = 0;

    // Max memory in bytes
    private long limit = 5000000;

    public MemoryCache() {
        // Use 25% of available heap size
        setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 4);
    }

    public void setLimit(long new_limit) {
        limit = new_limit;
        //Log.i(TAG, "MemoryCache will use up to " + limit / 1024. / 1024. + "MB");
    }

    public Bitmap get(String id) {
        try {
            if (!cache.containsKey(id))
                return null;
            return cache.get(id);
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {
            if (cache.containsKey(id))
                size -= getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
            cache.put(id, bitmap);
            size += getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
            checkSize();
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkSize() {
        //Log.i(TAG, "cache size=" + size + " length=" + cache.size());
        if (size > limit) {
            // Least recently accessed item will be the first one iterated
            Iterator<Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter = cache.entrySet().iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Entry<String, Bitmap> entry = iter.next();
                size -= getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
                iter.remove();
                if (size <= limit)
                    break;
            }
            //Log.i(TAG, "Clean cache. New size " + cache.size());
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        try {
            cache.clear();
            size = 0;
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap == null)
            return 0;
        return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    }
}
```

//After doing all this stuff now you have to call the image loader class file

```
ImageLoader imageloader = new ImageLoader(this);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage("url",
                imageview);
```

Comment: I tried but no use.. this is also taking a bit of time to load image into imageview.

Comment: Then you can download the image from url and save it into sdcard and next time taking the downloaded path and setting image from path.

Comment: i think it is also take a bit of time right. do u observe the profile in instagram?? actually my requirement is like that.. it should be fixed..

Comment: Its ok...whatever i know i had given apart from that i have no idea.

Comment: welcome then, if you found your solution then please let me know also.:)

Comment: i used instead of image view RoundImage and before calling that fragment in mainactivity i called the service so here i get the profile image url right. then i converted the url into bitmap. and bitmap should be static ..     Then image.setImageBitmap(bitmap) in the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Picasso Library is the most common practice to handle profile images

Picasso handles both round image and image caching. If you would like the image to persist even without connection you may do the following :

This method saves the bitmap image to local app folder in a directory named userphotos

```
 private void saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage, String userID){

        File image;
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
        File directory = cw.getDir("userphotos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Mode Private will overwrites file if exists

        mage = new File(directory, userID + ".jpg");

        FileOutputStream fos;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(image);
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

}

The following method loads image from local folder

```
 public static Bitmap getPhoto(Context context, String userID){

    Bitmap photo = null;

    File image;
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
    File directory = cw.getDir("userphotos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    image = new File(directory, userID + ".jpg");

    if(image.exists()){

        try {
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(image);
            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi);
            return photo;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }


    }

    return null;
```

}

Now you onlyhave to load the image from device if internet is available which you can check for with the following method

```
 public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

If internet is available you can load the image with Picasso. here you have 2 options...

1. You can load the image into your imageview so tyat you benefit from fading animation and caching and then load the image again with picasso but instead of putting the bitmap into an imageview you save the bitmap into the device folder with the 1st method I posted.
2. You load the image from the drive and you picasso to grab the image and put it into the device folder instead of an imageview.

Picasso..

Get Image File with path for Picasso:

```
public static File getImageFilePath(Context context, String userID){

    File imagePath;
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
    File directory = cw.getDir(PHOTOS_DIR, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    imagePath = new File(directory, userID + ".jpg");


    if(imagePath.exists()){

        return imagePath;

    }else{
        return null;
    }

}
```

Then load with picasso :

```
File filePath = getImageFilePath(context, userID);

Picasso.with(ctx).load(filePath).into(imageView);
```